# What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

What is the difference between the following lines of code?

```
//Function declaration
function foo() { return 5; }

//Anonymous function expression
var foo = function() { return 5; }

//Named function expression
var foo = function foo() { return 5; }
```

**Questions:**

1. What is a named/anonymous function expression?
2. What is a declared function?
3. How do browsers deal with these constructs differently?

What do the responses to a similar question ([var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)) not get exactly right?

Comment: Here's [a good article on named function expressions](http://kangax.github.com/nfe). Function expressions vs declarations are addressed in the first section.

Comment: The main difference IMO is hoisting.  Here is a good article on the topic: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: Fixed link to the [good article on named function expressions](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/).

Answer (score 431):

They're actually really similar. How you call them is exactly the same.The difference lies in how the browser loads them into the execution context.

Function declarations load before any code is executed.

Function expressions load only when the interpreter reaches that line of code.

So if you try to call a function expression before it's loaded, you'll get an error! If you call a function declaration instead, it'll always work, because no code can be called until all declarations are loaded.

**Example: Function Expression**

```
alert(foo()); // ERROR! foo wasn't loaded yet
var foo = function() { return 5; }
```

**Example: Function Declaration**

```
alert(foo()); // Alerts 5. Declarations are loaded before any code can run.
function foo() { return 5; }
```

As for the second part of your question:

`var foo = function foo() { return 5; }` is really the same as the other two. It's just that this line of code used to cause  an error in safari, though it no longer does.

Comment: The last one is not the same than ``var foo = function() { return 5; }``.
Because here, ``foo.name`` is ``''``, in the last one it is ``'foo'``.

Comment: @JCM AFAIK, the name property is not part of ECMAScript and is only implemented in some browsers. [`Function.name` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

Comment: @ZachL Just used as example, what I wanted to say is that the second function has a name, where the first one doesn't.

Comment: "But if you call a function declaration, it'll always work."

So then is there ever a benefit of using a function expression?  Why not just always use declarations?

Comment: It's actually considered a best practice to use function expressions as then the behavior is more intuitive than with declarations. It reads better as it follows a logical flow, You define it and then call it, if you don't you get an error, which is the expected behavior. Actually I think function declarations are not allowed in non function scopes...I recommend this post on the subject:
http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Comment: Check `function` hoisting in javascript for more clarifications. http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but what is the use of having function expressions over function declarations ?

Comment: Can I assume that *Function Expression* implements kind of *lazy* behaviour, similar to lazy initialization? I mean, it gets loaded only upon the request of interpreter.

Answer (score 113):

## Function Declaration

```
function foo() { ... }
```

Because of **function hoisting**, the function declared this way can be called both after and before the definition.

## Function Expression

1. **Named Function Expression**

   ```
   var foo = function bar() { ... }
   ```
2. **Anonymous Function Expression**

   ```
   var foo = function() { ... }
   ```

`foo()` can be called only after creation.

## [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/#iife)

```
(function() { ... }());
```

## Conclusion

Douglas Crockford recommends to use function expression in his «JavaScript: The Good Parts» book because it makes it clear that `foo` is a variable containing a function value.

Well, personally, I prefer to use Declaration unless there is a reason for Expression.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: point of interest: js is case-sensitive. Your caps-locked examples don't work ;-)

Comment: also, you *can* have a Named IIFE: `(function myFunc() { ... }());`

Comment: Shorter and widely used way to write IIFE: If you don't care about the return value, or the possibility of making your code slightly harder to read, you can save a byte by just prefixing the function with a unary operator. Example: 
`!function(){ /*code*/ }();` (source: [linked article](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/#iife))

Comment: @naXa - +1 for the link, well written article on IIFE :)

Comment: `function hoisting` & `variable hoisting` & `IIFE`

Comment: As my investigation, any functions in an expression will be function expression.

Answer (score 21):

Regarding 3rd definition:

```
var foo = function foo() { return 5; }
```

Heres an example which shows how to use possibility of recursive call:

```
a = function b(i) { 
  if (i>10) {
    return i;
  }
  else {
    return b(++i);
  }
}

console.log(a(5));  // outputs 11
console.log(a(10)); // outputs 11
console.log(a(11)); // outputs 11
console.log(a(15)); // outputs 15
```

Edit:
more interesting example with closures:

```
a = function(c) {
 return function b(i){
  if (i>c) {
   return i;
  }
  return b(++i);
 }
}
d = a(5);
console.log(d(3)); // outputs 6
console.log(d(8)); // outputs 8
```

Comment: You don't need to declare the function with a different name to make it recursive. In fact, I'd say that confuses things. `a = function a(i)` and doing `return a(++i)` produces the same result

Comment: But using a different name for the function than the variable illustrates the point more clearly. Kudos for providing an example for usage of named function expressions.

Answer (score 13):

The first statement depends on the context in which it is declared.

If it is declared in the global context it will create an implied global variable called "foo" which will be a variable which points to the function. Thus the function call "foo()" can be made anywhere in your javascript program.

If the function is created in a closure it will create an implied local variable called "foo" which you can then use to invoke the function inside the closure with "foo()"

**EDIT:**

I should have also said that function statements (The first one) are parsed before function expressions (The other 2). This means that if you declare the function at the bottom of your script you will still be able to use it at the top. Function expressions only get evaluated as they are hit by the executing code.

**END EDIT**

Statements 2 & 3 are pretty much equivalent to each other. Again if used in the global context they will create global variables and if used within a closure will create local variables. However it is worth noting that statement 3 will ignore the function name, so esentially you could call the function anything. Therefore

```
var foo = function foo() { return 5; }
```

Is the same as

```
var foo = function fooYou() { return 5; }
```

Comment: `fooYou` is not ignored. It is visible in function body, so the function can reference itself (e.g. to implement recursion).

Comment: That's a good point. I didn't think about that :)

Comment: Also, named function expressions are useful for debugging: `var foo = function fooYou() { return 5; }; console.log(foo); console.log(foo.name);` will print `fooYou() / fooYou` (Firefox), `[Function: fooYou] / fooYou` (node.js), `function fooYou() { return 5; } / fooYou` (Chrome) or something alone these lines, depending on where you execute it.

Comment: Named function expressions is the recommended practice since it allows you to refer the function internally, if you need. For instance, to call the function recursively or deal with its name or properties. The major benefit, by the way, is debugging. If you use unnamed functions it's hard to debug if something happen right there, since you will get a reference to an anonymous function and not its name

Answer (score 1):

Though the complete difference is more complicated, the only difference that concerns me is when the machine creates the function object. Which in the case of declarations is before any statement is executed but after a statement body is invoked (be that the global code body or a sub-function's), and in the case of expressions is when the statement it is in gets executed. Other than that for all intents and purposes browsers treat them the same.

To help you understand, take a look at this performance [test](http://jsperf.com/local-vs-global/7) which busted an assumption I had made of internally declared functions not needing to be re-created by the machine when the outer function is invoked. Kind of a shame too as I liked writing code that way.