# Why can I not define functions in jQuery's document.ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Functions come up as undefined if I place them in the document.ready() function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function foo()
  {
    alert('Bar');
  }
});

foo(); // Undefined
```

Why does this happen? I'm sure I'm just in need of some simple understanding :)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Not sure why defining the function with in the scope of `ready()` is important to you, but you can make it work by declaring `foo` up front:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var foo;                           // Here's the difference
$(document).ready(function(){
  foo = function ()
  {
    alert('Bar');
  }
});
</script></head><body>
<input type="button" onclick="foo()" value="Click me">
</body></html>
```

Obviously you can't call `foo()` from the inline script immediately after `ready()` because the `ready()` code hasn't yet run, but you can call the function later on.

Just make sure that nothing can try to call `foo()` before the `ready()` code has run (or make the initial declaration of `foo()` a harmless function).

Comment: What if you need to call `foo()` with some parameters? How would you pass them, and how would they be received?

Comment: @alonso.torres: Just like any other JavaScript function: `foo = function(x, y, z) {...}` ... `onclick="foo(1, 2, 3)"`

Comment: @RichieHindle note that "the way you declare the function" matters, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819425/jquery-document-ready-and-function-scope

Comment: @RichieHindle also, if you do NOT add `var foo` and leave the function declaration as you posted `foo = function (){}`, the variable `foo` will have the global scope assign to it. You can simply check this by doing `console.log(window.foo);` after the function was loaded.

Comment: @RichieHindle thanks for your solution, its working ;)

Answer (score 27):

You can but they must be called within the scope of the `ready()` method otherwise they lose scope when the `ready()` method exits.

For example, the code below will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function foo()
  {
    alert('Bar');
  }

  foo(); // still in the scope of the ready method
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to get around this? Change the scope?

Comment: Simple. Define them outside of the .ready(...) scope. I don't see why you're so attached to doing that. What benefit could it possibly offer you?

Comment: @Oli, it would have been better from a code organization standpoint to be able to declare it within the .ready() scope.

Comment: @James, it would NOT be better from a code standpoint, think of your foo() function as a library or API if it needs to be called from inside and outside the ready scope.  In which case, you make it take all necessary arguments and spit out a result, no side effects.

Answer (score 8):

They will come up as undefined if you put them in any scope that is not theirs.  If you really want to use them outside of the scope of $(document).ready(...) then you need to declare them externally.  Such as:

```
var foo;

$(document).ready(function(){
  foo = function()
  {
    alert('Bar');
  }
});

foo(); // works now because it is in scope
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @jj_ Hari Om''s solution works because the call to myfnc is within the same scope that myfnc is declared in.

Comment: yes `myfnc()` call is, but what about `myfnc(param1, param2)` in the input onclick event?

Comment: Because myfnc is not actually the name of the function. Hari Om creates an anonymous function and assigns it to the variable myfnc. Since the variable myfnc is global (variables in JScript have a global scope unless declared with "var"), it is visible outside the scope of ready(). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip for an explanation of the difference between function declaration and function expression

Answer (score 4):

Your function is defined within the scope of the `$(document).ready()` callback and cannot be *seen* from the *outside*. Either define the function outside the `$(document).ready()` scope of call it only from within.

Answer (score 2):

Just another addition:

When declaring functions or variables inside of the `$(document).ready()` function, these are inaccessible when using `onclick()` binds in the document.

You can either move your declarations outside of `$(document).ready()`, or you can use `$('#element').on('click', function() {})` within `$(document).ready().

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      myfnc = function (param1, param2)
      {
        alert('Hello');
      }
      myfnc();
    });
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="myfnc('arg1', 'arg2')" value="Click me">
```