# Wait for value to be defined without setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I'm grabbing a value from somewhere and wanting to use it locally (using lodash):

```js
const setting = _.get(this.settings, 'options');
```

`this.settings.options` is set somewhere else, and depending on the environment, `this.settings.options` may be undefined. In that case, I can do something like:

```js
const set = (setting) => {
  ...
  ...
};

const getThing = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const setting = _.get(this.settings, 'options');
    return setting ? set(setting) : getThing();
  }, 1000);
};

getThing();
```

This uses a `setTimeout` function to wait 1 second for `this.settings.options` to be set in that time, and if it's not yet set, the `setTimeout` function calls itself to check one second later. After that, it continues to the `set()` function with the acquired data. This seems to work every time, but it would be really nice if I could keep checking for this value until it is defined without a timer. I'm not sure if that's possible?

I've been trying to implement either a promise or use async / await to do this, but the examples I've seen also seem to use `setTimeout`s, and the solution ends up seemingly more complicated. Among others, I've mainly been looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56216283/7386637). Regardless, I'm having trouble doing this with async / await and will have to continue troubleshooting that.

Is there a way to wait for this value to be defined without using a `setTimeout` or `setInterval`?

Comment: You can use `set` method to handle setting the setting, and in that method call a callback function, which tells you that this setting has just been set. You could even use event listeners to do this and then it would be something like addEventListener('setting-was-set', setting => /* use setting here */)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener

Comment: Yes, there's almost always a better way than polling with timeouts for the value to appear. However, please tell us more about "*`this.settings.options` is set somewhere else, and depending on the environment, it may be `undefined`.*". Where exactly is "somewhere else", is it still in the same unit of code, and when does the setting happen? Or when does the environment decide that the option stays `undefined`?

Comment: sometimes this code operates in a local environment, and other times it's working with a receiver unit. There is a possible delay when the receiver unit is involved. In this particular scenario, the only place I can query for this data is whatever is inside `this.settings.options`, so there's not a workaround other than waiting for that property to be set (not sure if that's what you're looking for)

Comment: @rpivovar but your code knows whether there is a receiver unit or not, up-front? And it can call methods of that receiver unit? Maybe you can post the code of the receiver unit.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) due to misunderstanding of Promises and asynchrony in general. Please paste your real program and explain what problem it is trying to solve. Show example inputs and outputs. See related: [_How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no straightforward way to do it.

If you can mutate `this.settings` (and `this.settings.options` is at least configurable), then you can define a setter, and wait for it to be triggered.

This is generally an ugly pattern (use it only if there's no other way), but still better than periodically checking the existence of a property.

Also **note that** this will work only if the mysterious code that sets `.options` uses `[[Set]]` (i.e., `obj.prop = value` or `Reflect.set`), and not `[[Define]]` (i.e., `Object.defineProperty`).

```js
if(typeof this.settings.options==='undefined'){
  //Define a setter
  Object.defineProperty(this.settings, 'options', {
    set: (value)=>{
      //Remove setter, and transform to simple property
      Object.defineProperty(this.settings, 'options', {value})
      //Hypothetical function to be called with the result
      doSomethingWithTheValue(value)
    },
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true
  })
}else{
  doSomethingWithTheValue(this.settings.options)
}
```

And, you can now easily rewrite this to a general function that uses `Promise`s (and therefore supports `async`/`await`):

```js
function getAsync(obj, prop){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    if(typeof obj[prop]==='undefined'){
      Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
        set: (value)=>{
          Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {value})
          resolve(value)
        },
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true
      })
    }else{
      resolve(obj[prop])
    }
  })
}

getAsync(this.settings,'options')
  .then(doSomethingWithTheValue)

//or, async/await:

(async()=>{
  const value=await getAsync(this.settings,'options')
  doSomethingWithTheValue(value)
})
```