# For of loop, wait until value is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

In a `for of` loop, I want to get a value defined (not empty) **before** I continue to the next iteration.

Currently, I do a `setTimeout()` and "hope" that the value is available after 3 seconds. Poor practice.

Is there a way to pause the loop iteration until the value is available, and *then* continue the loop?

```
// get a tags in array
const $j_object = $(".name");
        
for (const element of $j_object) {

    // timeout
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

    // get value
    value_name = await GM.getValue("value_name");

    // wait until value_name is defined until we continue...!
}
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you please post an answer demonstrating this with my code as reference? Thanks.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Why couldn't you? `await` works perfectly in a `for` loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [While variable is not defined - wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307983/while-variable-is-not-defined-wait)

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of `while ((value_name = await GM.getValue('value_name')) === undefined) await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500))`

Comment: I think `await` is good ideal? why you don't try that?

Comment: @JeremyThille that's a good point. I didn't test `await`, however the OP is already using it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but not to keep checking for the value - they are using it to load the value only once.

Comment: @CherryDT Your solution actually works. Please post as an answer explaining it so that i can accept it.

Comment: It may work, but note that the `while` loop with freeze the browser. What work does `GM.getValue()` do? Can you not amend it to work with promises more effectively, by resolving when it *actually has a value*?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : No it won't freeze the browser, there is an `await` in the `while`.

Comment: Why is `GM.getValue` returning a value that isn't defined yet?

Comment: Ugh, I keep missing the damn `await`. My bad. However I'd argue the pattern should be changed so that whatever logic is called in `GM.getValue()` works with the promises more effectively, as I stated in the previous comment.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan agreed - this design seems fundamentally flawed/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: [GM.getValue](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM.getValue) reads a value from Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey's local storage, I'm assuming it will be set by some separate piece of code at some point. There may not be a way to have those pieces communicate. But if there were, then of course using an event emitter would be preferred.

Comment: Understood. The `GM` naming convention now makes sense. Tagging that in the question may have been helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a loop in which you keep reading the value, with some delay between the reading attempts, breaking the loop when you read something other than `undefined`.

```js
while ((value_name = await GM.getValue('value_name')) === undefined) {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500))
}
```

A less dense way of writing that would be:

```js
while (true) {
  value_name = await GM.getValue('value_name')
  if (value_name !== undefined) break
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500))
}
```

Comment: Regarding the `do` approach, how is that different to the first approach (the setTimeout one)? As in, how often will `do` check the value?

Comment: I fixed my second example because it wasn't equivalent, the timeout was missing