# Uncaught ReferenceError: checkAvailability is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have to define different functions in my project and they all rely on jQuery, so I have to make sure that they are inside the document-ready function. When I place them there, I get the error described bellow. How can this be fixed? The jQuery lib seems to be included correctly.

In `<head>`:

```
<script src="js/lib/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     function checkAvailability() {
        ...
     }
});
```

When I try to access the function later on, I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: checkAvailability is not defined
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055767/why-can-i-not-define-functions-in-jquerys-document-ready

Comment: When are you calling `checkAvailability`

Comment: better to put the function outside of `doc ready`

Comment: After a click on a button on the page, so by then it should be loaded. @Ram I tried that already, but it says `undefined is not a function`. @Tarun Pai, if I do this, `.serialize()` does not work.

Comment: If they *rely on jQuery*, then they only need to be placed after the jQuery inclusion. Only if they need to wait for the DOM (and a function *declaration* hardly needs), they would need to be placed inside `ready`.

Comment: @doonot: Please show us the code of how you attach the listener to the click event.

Comment: `<a class="btn" onclick="checkAvailability();">Check</a>`

Comment: @doonot okay then if you put your function outside of doc ready then it will work perfectly fine. Although i am not a big fan of inline events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a scoping issue...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     function checkAvailability() {
        ...
     }

    checkAvailability() // can be called here as the definition is in scope
});

checkAvailability() // Can't be called here
```

Instead, define your function outside the jQuery method...

```
function checkAvailability() {
   ...
}

$( document ).ready(function() {

    checkAvailability() // can be called here
});
checkAvailability() // Or here
```

Think of function declaration scope in the same way you would variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put all your event actions in the `doc ready` handler and functions you can put outside of it:

```
function checkAvailability() {
    ...
 }

$( document ).ready(function() {
  your click event should be here....
});
```