# js form validation error: Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I am using php to store information into a database and I want to use javascript to validate the form. I created a separate javascript file for form validation, which is included in index.php, but whenever I click submit and look at console in google's developer tools I get:

```
index.php:92 Uncaught ReferenceError: popupValidation is not definedonsubmit @ index.php:92
```

Here is the code:

index.php

```
            <form name="popup" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" onsubmit="return popupValidation();" method="post">
            <div class="row">
              <input name="firstName" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
              <input name="lastName" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="youremail@email.com">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="password">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <input name="repeatPass" type="password" class="form-control" id="retypePassword" placeholder="Retype password">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <input name="trainer" type="checkbox"/> Sign up as trainer
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer popup-footer">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit" value="Register">
           </div> 
          </form>
```

popupvalidation.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function popupValidation() {
    var fname = document.forms["popup"]["firstName"].value;
    var lname = document.forms["popup"]["lastName"].value;
    var pass = document.forms["popup"]["password"].value;
    var repass = document.forms["popup"]["repeatPass"].value;
    var email = document.forms["popup"]["email"].value;

    if (fname==null || fname=="", lname==null || lname=="", pass==null || pass=="",
      repass==null || repass=="", email==null || email=="") {
        alert("Pleases fill out field");
        return false;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I not define functions in jQuery's document.ready()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055767/why-can-i-not-define-functions-in-jquerys-document-ready)

Answer (score 0):

it seems like u have a scope issue, you will need to move the popupValidation function to the global scope