# How to make a href appended in search bar select option in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have built a one page website that is broken up by section and each section has ids. My client wants to be able to navigate to each section using a href (#'s) in the search bar like

```
www.website#gohere
```

And with my sections, this works well. My problem is they just threw a curve ball and I don't know how to go about doing this -

On my page in a certain section called #labSearch I have  a dropdown that is populated from a csv file using jQuery here:

```
var location = arrayOfEvents[i][0];

    if (location != prevLoc)
    {
    select.innerHTML += "<option id = "+"test" +" value=\"" + location + "\">" + location + "</option>";
    }
```

When a dropdown option is selected, certain divs show up according to the value of the dropdown. They need it so that say the dropdown option is Dallas, when they go:

```
website.com#Dallas
```

It takes them to the section with the dropdwin (this is #labSearch) and acts as if the user has selected the Dallas option, meaning the right divs are displayed. I have tried as you can see above giving the options ids, however this does nothing.

How can I make an a href in the search bar select a certain dropdown option? Is this possible?

Why won't the option id work?

Here is my dropdown code in my labSearch section:

```
<form id="locationForm" style = "width: 70%; margin: auto; padding-bottom: 30px;">
  <select class = "form-control" id="selectNumber" style = "">
    <option>Choose a location</option>
  </select>


</form>
```

EDIT: Ok at the end of my javascript outside of document ready or anything I have:

```
var selectHashOption = function () {
        console.log("hash changed");
    var select1 = document.getElementById('selectNumber');
    var parts = location.href.split('#');
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        var hash = parts[1];    // Get the hash part of the URL
      console.log("HASH="+hash);
        select1.value = hash;   // Select the option in the dropdown list
        //select1.onchange();
      dropdownChange();
      // Trigger the onchange event handler
    }
};

window.onhashchange = selectHashOption;
});

    </script>
```

This all works well, except I am unable to call dropdownChange - I get that it is undefined, however I have declared the variable at file scope here:

```
<script>

var dropdownChange;
```

Then set it in document ready:

```
$(".form-control").change(function () {

                  dropdownChange = function()
                  {
                    //stuff
```

This was explained here [Why can I not define functions in jQuery's document.ready()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055767/why-can-i-not-define-functions-in-jquerys-document-ready) and I did it as they did. This is BEFORE my hash change window stuff. I can't even call `onchange` because that is undefined as well. What can I do?

EDIT 2:

I now have my func declared initially at scope level then set here:

```
dropdownChange = function () {
}
$(".form-control").change(dropdownChange);
```

In my hash stuff after I tried:

```
if (parts.length > 1) {
        var hash = parts[1];    // Get the hash part of the URL
      console.log("HASH="+hash);
        select1.value = hash;   // Select the option in the dropdown list
        select1.onchange();

    }
```

and got same this function is undefined. I then call the function directly with:

```
if (parts.length > 1) {
        var hash = parts[1];    // Get the hash part of the URL
      console.log("HASH="+hash);
        select1.value = hash;   // Select the option in the dropdown list
        dropdownChange();

    }
```

And the function is called but the value (I `console.log(this.value)`) is undefined here -

[image]

Comment: Im not sure I follow.. you want the correct option in the dropdown to be selected based on the hash in your url?

Comment: Yes, and to navigate to that section of the page. I.e. the dallas option is selected - it navigates to the dropdown on the pg and has dallas selected in the dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select an option by setting the `value` attribute of the dropdown list. I assume that the option value matches the hash part of the URL typed by the user.

For this HTML markup:

```
<select id="select1">
    <option value="Dallas">Dallas</option>
    <option value="New York">New York</option>
    <option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
    <option value="Chicago">Chicago</option>
</select>
```

You can select the option that matches the hash part of the URL with this code:

```
var selectHashOption = function () {
    var select1 = document.getElementById('select1');
    var parts = location.href.split('#');
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        var hash = parts[1];    // Get the hash part of the URL
        select1.value = hash;   // Select the option in the dropdown list
        select1.onchange();     // Trigger the onchange event handler
    }
};

window.onhashchange = selectHashOption;
```

Once the option is selected, I call `onchange` to trigger the event handler of the dropdown list. Depending on the way the event handler was set, you may need to do it differently, as mentioned in [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually).

I needed to monitor the `onhashchange` event to make it work in my test code, as you can see on the last line of the code sample.

Comment: Alright thank you - now having a problem with my function scope/dynamic. It sets the correct value to the dropdown but can't call on change or any other function (trying to call the function I would normally call) because it thinks it is undefined. See edit asbove

Comment: Could you define your function as `var dropDownChange = function () { ... };` and assign the event handler as `$(".form-control").change(dropDownChange);`? That way, you could call `dropDownChange` from anywhere, I think.

Comment: Ok - I now have it calling the func properly but it isn't getting the value of the dropdown option see above

Comment: It's because `this` is not the dropdown list in `dropDownChange`. You should define `var dropDownChange  = function (ddl) { /* use ddl instead of this */ };`, and call it like this: `dropDownChange(select1)`.

Comment: With my last suggestion, you would also have to redefine the event handler as: `$(".form-control").change(function () { dropDownChange(this); });`.

Comment: Thank you so much - do you know how to make the window navigate to that part of the page as well? I have tried setting the window.href to #cities (because thats where it needs to go) but that screws up the dropdown

Comment: You can try the methods suggested in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript. Some of them scroll the page without modifying the hash.