# onclick for button not calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

One of the problems I am experiencing at the moment is not being able to call a function in the `onclick` event of the submit button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function validate() {
    var contactName = document.getElementById("contact-name").value;
    alert("Thank you " + contactName);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="name">NAME</label>
  <input id="contact-name" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your name..." type="text">
  <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
  <input id="contact-email" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your contact email..." type="text">
  <label for="email">MESSAGE</label>
  <textarea id="contact-message" name="message" placeholder="Please enter your message.."></textarea>
</form>

<button type="button" id="submit" onclick="validate();">SUBMIT MESSAGE</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I not define functions in jQuery's document.ready()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055767/why-can-i-not-define-functions-in-jquerys-document-ready)

Comment: validate() is not getting called
you're just defining it but never calling it

Comment: @SoumeshBanerjee It’s in the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: First of all, that's not submit button and it's defined outside the form so it will not submit all the value on submit action. and you don't need to define validate() function inside document.ready.

Answer (score 4):

You should write the `validate()` function *outside* the `$(document).ready` as the `onclick` in binded *when* the DOM loads - while `$(document).ready` *scopes* the function.

This means the function is *local* to the *closure* and will not be visible *globally* if its written so inside `$(document).ready`.

See demo below:

```js
function validate() {
  var contactName = document.getElementById("contact-name").value;
  alert("Thank you " + contactName);

}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">NAME</label>
  <input id="contact-name" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your name..." type="text">
  <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
  <input id="contact-email" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your contact email..." type="text">
  <label for="email">MESSAGE</label>
  <textarea id="contact-message" name="message" placeholder="Please enter your message.."></textarea>
</form>

<button type="button" id="submit" onclick="validate();">SUBMIT MESSAGE</button>
```

Comment: Well, you have described the problem correctly, but your solution is not really very good because it keeps the inline HTML event attribute (which is really the source of the problem in the first place). If the inline HTML is removed and modern event binding occurs in JavaScript (inside the `document.ready` scope), then all will be well.

Comment: @ScottMarcus hey, that is not a reason to down vote!!

Comment: Ohh well, sorry I assumed it was you

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the issue here is the scope that the `validate()` function is defined in.

JavaScript is **["lexically scoped"](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/20/javascript-scope-closures/)**, meaning that the location of a declaration determines from where it can be reached by other code.

Your `validate` function is declared (scoped to) inside the anonymous `document.ready` function. This means that the only place where `validate` can be "seen" is by other code that shares that scope. The `onclick=validate()` line is outside of that scope and that is why your function isn't being called.

However, instead of moving the `validate()` function outside of the `document.ready()` callback (thus making it global, which is a bad thing), you really should remove the `onclick` inline HTML event attribute as this is a bad practice (**[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)** for several reasons why) and do the event binding in the script area. This approach will allow you to set up the event in the same scope as the `validate()` function and keep the HTML clean:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Do your event binding in JavaScript, not as inline HTML event attributes:
  $("#submit").on("click", validate);

  // Now the event handler reference and the function are in the same scope
  function validate() {
    var contactName = document.getElementById("contact-name").value;
    alert("Thank you " + contactName);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="name">NAME</label>
  <input id="contact-name" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your name..." type="text">
  <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
  <input id="contact-email" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your contact email..." type="text">
  <label for="email">MESSAGE</label>
  <textarea id="contact-message" name="message" placeholder="Please enter your message.."></textarea>
</form>

<button type="button" id="submit">SUBMIT MESSAGE</button>
```

Here's a bit more on **[scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385835/invocation-context-and-execution-context-in-javascript-are-we-talking-of-th/41386097#41386097)**.

Answer (score -1):

First, you should avoid inline handlers like that. Second, depending on the form submission process. You should have the button inside your `<form>` tags. Then add `<form method="POST" action="/someurl/to/post/to">`.

Otherwise, use jQuery and `$.ajax()` with a `click` event handler:

```
$('#submit').on('click', () {
  $.ajax({check properties in jquery api docs}, (result) => { 
      // do something 
    }, 
    (e) => { 
      // do something on error 
  })
})
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the problem. Also, HTML5 allows for form elements to exist outside of the `form` element as long as those elements have the `form` attribute.

Comment: Sure, buttons can go anywhere, doesn't mean they should.

Comment: No, you misunderstand. It is perfectly legal and valid for a button to go outside of a `form`. It is not correct to say that they "should" go inside the form.