# How to get a shareable link for a hidden content opened dynamically using JS or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This question is related to this post: [Implementing navigation side bar to load <div>s link click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893974/implementing-navigation-side-bar-to-load-divs-link-click)

What I want is basically to be able to change and load content on the right part of a website by clicking links on the sidebar.

The code below was from the post I mentioned above.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadContent(selector){
        $("#loadOnClick").html($(selector).html());
    };

    
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
        loadContent("#userGuide");
    
    });
</script>
<style>
div.container11 {
    width: 100%;
    
}
section.container1{
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
}

.displayInline{
    -webkit-flex: 1;  /* Safari 6.1+ */
    -ms-flex: 1;  /* IE 10 */    
    flex: auto;
}

header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: powderblue;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    border-right: 2px solid gray;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
   
nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 30px;
}

div#loadOnClick {
    float: right;
}

 .displayOnClick{
    display: none;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<header>
   <h1>My Company</h1>
</header>

 <section id="container1">
    <nav class="displayInLine" style="width: 20%; float: left;">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#userGuide" class="quickLinks" onclick='loadContent("#userGuide")'>User Guide</a></li>
        <li><a href="#SOP" class="quickLinks" onclick='loadContent("#SOP")'>SOP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#procedurePages" class="quickLinks" onclick='loadContent("#procedurePages")'>Procedure pages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#departmentInformation" class="quickLinks" onclick='loadContent("#departmentInformation")'>Department information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#hoursOfOperations" class="quickLinks" onclick='loadContent("#hoursOfOperations")'>Hours of operations</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="displayInLine" id="loadOnClick" style="width:75%; float: right;">
        
    </div>
</section>

<div id="userGuide" class="displayOnClick">
    <h1>User Guide</h1>
    <p>This is the userguide for employees</p>
</div>

<div id="SOP" class="displayOnClick">
    <h1>SOP</h1>
    <p>This is the Statement of purpose for employees</p>
</div>

<div id="procedurePages" class="displayOnClick">
    <h1>Procedure pages</h1>
    <p>This is the Procedure pages for employees</p>
</div>

<div id="departmentInformation" class="displayOnClick">
    <h1>Department information</h1>
    <p>This is the Department information for employees</p>
</div>

<div id="hoursOfOperations" class="displayOnClick">
    <h1>Hours of operations</h1>
    <p>This is the Hours of operations for employees</p>
</div>

<footer>Copyright &copy; Om Sao</footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It does this well, but the only thing missing is to get a shareable link to others. So for example if I share the link `docs.html#Overview` to others, they'll be able to open exactly the page I've specified.

Right now, if I give a link to others containing a `#` it still loads by default and not go to the specific page.

I'm planning to use it for a documentation part, so it's very important a certain page is shareable. How do I go about to changing this script to handle this?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Don't write inline event handlers (`onclick="...")` into your HTML, it's not 1995 anymore. Especially when you are using jQuery, which has been *made* to allow convenient event handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a lot you need to do, most of it is already built into how HTML works.

Links with `href="#something"` set the page URL to `"...#something"`. That's called the hash. It's accessible through `location.hash` in JavaScript. Those URLs *already are* bookmarkable.

Loading a page with a hash will make the browser scroll to the element with that ID, and jQuery/CSS selectors will find the element with that ID, so you can use the element's `href` and the `location.hash` directly in code.

jQuery only needs to handle toggling the element visibility when the hash changes due to link clicks. Conveniently, the browser issues [`hashchange` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event) whenever the `location.hash` changes.

```js
$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
  $('.linkTargets > *:visible').addClass('hidden');
  $('.linkTargets ' + location.hash).removeClass('hidden');
});

$(function() {
  // trigger the change handler once at page load
  if (location.hash) $(window).trigger('hashchange');

  $('#simulateLoad').click(function () {
    location.hash = '#procedurePages';
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#userGuide">User Guide</a></li>
  <li><a href="#SOP">SOP</a></li>
  <li><a href="#procedurePages">Procedure pages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#departmentInformation">Department information</a></li>
  <li><a href="#hoursOfOperations">Hours of operations</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="linkTargets">
  <div id="userGuide" class="hidden">
    <p>This is the userguide for employees</p>
  </div>
  <div id="SOP" class="hidden">
    <p>This is the Statement of purpose for employees</p>
  </div>
  <div id="procedurePages" class="hidden">
    <p>This is the Procedure pages for employees</p>
  </div>
  <div id="departmentInformation" class="hidden">
    <p>This is the Department information for employees</p>
  </div>
  <div id="hoursOfOperations" class="hidden">
    <p>This is the Hours of operations for employees</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="simulateLoad">Simulate page load for #procedurePages</button>
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! I'm still learning and I will take a really good look to understand how you did what you did in this script. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach,

1. Fetch the current url using, **window.location.href**
2. split the url and get the string after #.
3. With that you can hide and show the specific data (May be onload)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `loadContent("#userGuide");` inside your document ready function to `loadContent(window.location.href.replace(“docs.html/or your host“,””));`