# javascript create function

Tags: javascript, function

What is the difference between this:

```
var doSomething=function()
{
    //do blah blah blah...  
}
```

And this:

```
function doSomething()
{
    //do blah blah blah...  
}
```

Another question:
In PHP, we create a function by doing this:

```
function doSomething(a,b)
{
    //do something to variable a and b...
}
```

In JavaScript, we may have an object before the function:

```
object.doSomething(a);
```

My second question is, how would you create a function which requires an object in JavaScript?

Comment: difference is that second function is defined at parse-time for a script block, whereas the first function is defined at run-time

Comment: possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number one Google result for "function statement vs expression javascript" is another Stack Overflow question:

[What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascript)

It references the following article, which is the definitive reference on the subject:

http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

Comment: For questions related to the javascript language itself, I found the book "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide", By David Flanagan - really helpful. However, for this particular question, I believe the links provided are an even better source =)

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `var fun = function() {}` and `function fun() {}` is that in the first case it is stored in the variable `fun`. To call the function, you have to call `fun()`. Having it in a variable lets you pass the function around.

You can create objects by using functions

```
function MyClass() {
    this.fun = function() { alert('Hello world'); }
}

var obj = new MyClass();
obj.fun();
```

or JSON

```
var obj = {
   fun: function() { alert('Hello world'); }
};

obj.fun();
```

You can further extend the objects or their prototypes with new functions.

Edit. Sorry for the wrong answer: one shouldn't try to do these kinds of things at 4 am.

Comment: @Aleksi: Even for the second function you need to call fun(); at some point.

Comment: In neither case is the function executed immediately. To invoke the function immediately it would have to be var fun = function(){}(); or function fun() {}()

Comment: The body of the function is not executed immediately in either case.

Comment: You are absolute right, my mistake. Both are definitions, not calls. The first one just lets you use a functions as a variable and pass it around. Upvotes allaround for rapid corrections!

Comment: Your first example is completely wrong, you're setting 'fun' on the window object and then setting obj to `undefined`.

Comment: @david Not completely - just missing the new keyword. I stand by my assertion that these answers shouldn't be written at 4 am.

Answer (score 0):

One question at a time.

To answer your first question, there is not a huge difference.

```
function doSomething() {}
```

is technically equivalent to:

```
var doSomething;
doSomething = function() {};
```

technically what happens in this case is the variable declaration gets [hoisted](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) to the top of your script.

Comment: They're not quite equivalent, the first one hoists the definition as well as the declaration, the second only hoists the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of the question, we just do something like

```
object.doSomething = function(a) { ... }
```

which is one reason the function literal is so useful.