# WHy doesn't Netbeans also mark functions as occurences (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, netbeans

The mark occurences option in Netbeans doesn't work on function names for me. I'm on version 6.9.1. Anybody know how to possibly make that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use functions expressions, like this:

```
var func;

func = function () {
    //code
};
```

Then Netbeans marks it too. I couldn't find another way.

Remember about declaring variables for future functions. Notice a semicolon after definition.

Also [this answer should be helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascript)

Comment: @Lou Bandy: Generally Netbeans is a good editor, although I found some nasty memory leak bugs when it tried to resolve the type of an object.