# JavaScript differences defining a function

Tags: javascript, function

I just bought the newest version of "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide" and already have a question. :D

Are the following lines semantically the same:

```
var square = function(n){
                 return n * n;
             };
```

and

```
function square(n){
    return n * n;
}
```

If yes, what are the advantages/disadvantages of using either of them?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, Felix. The differences between these two approaches are now clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

```
a(); // prints 'A'

function a(){

    console.log('A');

};
```

and this:

```
b(); // throws error. b is not a function

var b = function() {

    console.log('B');

};
```

Did you notice the difference?

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they do the exact same thing.

The main advantage of the first approach is that it gives you a reference to that function so that you could pass it to another function or attach it to an object if you need to.

Comment: I agree with the first sentence but if they both do the exact same thing, how can one be different from the other?

Comment: You can do the same with a function declaration (passing and assigning).

Answer (score 0):

Difference is that in the first solution, you can do that :

```
var square = function(n){
                 return n * n;
             };

// some code

square = function(n) { return n*n*n; }
```

you have **reference** to a function. On the other solution, the function is statically declared.

Disclaimer: need JS guru to tell me if I'm wrong =).

Comment: Hi Clement, to be honest, I don't understand what the last line does. Could you kindly explain me the purpose of **return n*n*n;** when I want to calculate the square?

Comment: Your example is a function that return the square value of a number, but that could be any other function, that does complicated, or really context-dependent work. Returning `n*n*n` for a square method is silly, but it is just for the example.