# Why are anonymous functions treated differently from named functions here?

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Javascript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)
>   [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascript)

Today I stumbled upon the following phenomenon:

```
foo();
bar();

function foo()
{
    console.log("inside foo");
}

var bar = function()
{
    console.log("inside bar");
}
```

FireBug complains with the following error message:

> bar is not a function

Several tutorials claim that `function f()` and `var f = function()` are basically the same thing. Evidently, they are not, but what exactly is going on here?

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascript

Comment: Just to clarify: This is not only a phenomenon of *anonymous* functions, but of function *expressions*. You can also have *named* functions as function expressions and you will see the same effect, but you cannot have anonymous function declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function *declarations* are available anywhere in the scope they're defined in, even before their physical definitions.

`var bar = function() { ... };` is a normal variable that happens to hold a function.  Like all other variables, it can only be used after its assigned.
(You cannot observe the future value of a variable)