# did prototype create a variable without using var?

Tags: javascript

```
Blog.prototype.signature = "TEXT"
```

did this statement here created a signature variable?

because this statement didnt have **var keyword** in it.

**Also additional question**

why need to use function literals or function reference to make a function inside the prototype of an object?

ex. this wont work....

```
obj.prototype.toString{

    return "dfasdfa";

}
```

Comment: this syntax is not correct, the toString one

Answer (score 1):

> did this statement here created a signature variable?

No, it set a property on the prototype of the `Blog` class.

> why need to use function literals or function reference to make a function inside the prototype of an object?

Because you need to assign something to the property `obj.prototype.toString`. You have to set it to equal something (in this case, function), which you're not doing with the code snippet you displayed.

**Example:**

```
obj.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "dfasdfa";
}
```

Note that you're actually assigning a value to that property with the `= function` bit. Then you go on to declare the function later on.

Comment: Nope. The key word here is `property`. You're setting a *property* on an object, as opposed to creating a variable.

Comment: @user1393669: You have a variable "Blog" (which seems to be a function). Then you [access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) the object on the "prototype" property and assign a new value to its "signature" property.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: To be correct, that is not a *function declaration*, but a *function expression*.

Comment: @Bergi: Is that so? What is the difference?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1013385/1048572)