# Why can't I access a property of an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I'm building my own photo gallery in javascript, partially for the experience, partially for a project. Right now, I'm getting stuck with some issues around objects.

When an Image object is created, it is pushed to an array in the Gallery object. Around the comment `// constrain to width` (line 55 in the gist), I'm trying to get the `width` and `height` properties from the object. If I console.log the variable `img`, I can see the properties and functions of the object. However, if I `console.log(img.height);`, I get undefined. What am I doing wrong?

The entire file is below. It's also [here in a gist](https://gist.github.com/2766269) for easier reading.

```
var Image = function(img, gallery){
    // init with an image in jquery form
    this.src = img.attr('src');

    this.setDimensions = function(){
        var temp_height, temp_width;
        $this = this;
        $this.image = $('<img />').attr('src', this.src).load(function(){
            $this.height = this.height;
            $this.width = this.width;
        });
    };

    // init functions
    this.setDimensions();
    gallery.images.push(this);


}; // Image

var Gallery = function(){
    this.width = $(window).width();
    this.height = $(window).height();
    this.images = [];

    this.createElements = function(){
        $('body').append('<div id="the_gallery"></div>');
        $('#the_gallery').css({width: this.width, height: this.height});
    };

    this.open = function(){
        this.createElements();

        var img = this.images[0];

        // see if the image is bigger than the window
        if( this.width >= img.width && this.height >= img.height) {
            console.log('image < window');
            // just show the image, centered
        }

        else {
            console.log('image > window');
            var temp_width, temp_height;
            // constrain to height
            if( img.width < img.height ) {
                console.log('image width < image height');
                temp_height = this.height;
                temp_width = (temp_height/img.height) * img.width;

                img.css({height:temp_height, width:temp_width});

            }

            // constrain to width
            else {
                console.log('image width > image height');
                temp_width = this.width;
                temp_height = (temp_width/img.width) * img.height;
                img.image.css({height:temp_height, width:temp_width});
            }

        }

        img.image.appendTo($('#the_gallery'));

    }; // open

    this.close = function(){
        $('#the_gallery').remove();
    }; // close
}; // Gallery

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#gallery img').click(function(){
        launchGallery($(this));
    }); // click

    var gallery = new Gallery(),
        test = new Image($('#gallery img:first'), gallery);

    gallery.open();
}); // doc ready
```

Comment: So that I might ask better questions, why the down vote and the vote to close?

Comment: "If I console.log the variable img, I can see the properties and functions of the object. However, if I console.log(img.height);" <-- This is either a false statement, the console.log's are not at the same location, or the version of console.log is "caching" the output (this last can happen in Chrome, try FF).

Comment: @pst it's a timing/async issue, that is actually happening. I was puzzled too.

Comment: @pst Appears it's the cacheing issue - FF doesn't show the properties in the log. Time to fix the async issue.

Comment: This probably isn't related to your immediate problem, but **you should rename your object**.  `Image` is a built-in host object (DOM 0); overwriting it (which you are doing) could cause other scripts to break.

Comment: @josh3736 thought that might cause a problem. I'll update that for sure. Thanks!

Comment: @hookedonwinter Again, that statement holds true. Address that first for a reliably diagnostic base *and* will allow writing a **useful** title. I didn't down-vote, but I will not up-vote either.

Comment: Why use function expressions when function declarations are available?

Comment: Updated the gist with working code that allows for the async issues. Just starting development, so things are likely to change. Thanks everyone for your help! https://gist.github.com/2766269

Comment: @RobG Most likely because I don't know the difference. Googled, and am now reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip to learn.

Comment: Cool, make sure you read [kangax's linked article](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/). Unusual that you hadn't come across declarations before, I think they are preferable to expressions where either will do the job. But of course expressions are very useful when used appropriately.

Comment: @RobG Well, i've come across them, just didn't really understand the difference and why one is better than the either. Either way, thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I voted for closing, but here is some help:

When you call `new Image`, you reload it and set `width` and `height` when the `load` event fires. That is *after* the rest of the code runs - when you get to that point line 55, the image might not be loaded yet.

A simple solution would be to just grab the width/height directly from `img.width()` and always run the plugin on `window.onload`. If you want to support dynamically loaded images you'll have to brush up on that logic, and wait until everything is loaded before building the gallery.

Also, avoid leaking globals, you're missing `var` in `$this = this` (line 7).

Comment: Ah, didn't consider the timing issue. The console suggests the problem is elsewhere (https://skitch.com/hookedonwinter/85ih1/index.html), but, I'll definitely update that. I'm reloading it as the image is displayed as a thumbnail originally - via css not a different image - so the `.width()` was only showing 100px.

Comment: Spot check in FF shows it's definitely a timing issue. Thanks!

Comment: @hookedonwinter here's a quick rewrite with this issue in mind: http://jsbin.com/ibudok/2/

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about this: but its worth a try.
Instead of "$('#the_gallery').css({width: this.width, height: this.height});"

Maybe try this:

"$('#the_gallery').css('width', this.width +'px').css('height', this.height +'px');"

Comment: That part works fine. It's lower down, with img.width and img.height