# Difference in object construction behavior in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip)

What is the difference in behavior between these two implementations? Is `MyType` still a constructor function in `Implementation 1`

Implementation 1:

```
var MyType = function() { 

}; 

var myObject = new MyType();
```

Implementation 2:

```
function MyType() { 

}

var myObject = new MyType();
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the code inside these constructors?

Comment: @Lèse majesté I use the `init` idiom to encapsulate constructor-like functionality. Is there a better way? These types have been stripped of functionality for the purposes of the question here of course. I immediately create a `that` variable to ensure I get consistent `this` behavior.

Comment: @Ben yes there are better ways (look into prototypes and function binding), they are also irrelevant to your question so I removed them to make it easier to quickly see the difference between the implementations.