# Misunderstanding in Javascript statements

Tags: javascript, function, function-pointers

I've just started working with javascript and I saw something which I can't explain.
I have js file named TestClass.js and its the following:

```
TestClass.SetError = function (errorDescription, errorCode, typedErrorCode)
{
    alert("SetError ");
}  

function SetError2(errorCode)
{
    alert("SetError2 ");
}
```

Can someone please explain me the difference between the SetError and SetError2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip)

Comment: Another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first piece of code (SetError) contains `Anonymous Function Expression`, where the second piece of code (SetError2) cotains a `Function Declaration`. See [Function Declarations vs. Function Expressions](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/)

Another good article: [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/)

Excerpt:

> function declarations are parsed and evaluated before any other
>   expressions are. Even if declaration is positioned last in a source,
>   it will be evaluated **foremost any other expressions** contained in a
>   scope.

That's basically the main difference. It's not huge but worth being aware of.

Answer (score 1):

SetError is a method of the object TestClass. Whereas SetError2 is a global function.

Answer (score 1):

the difference lies in how the browser loads them into the execution context.

function loads before any code is executed.

While expressions loads only when the interpreter reaches that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

`SetError2` is a "named" method. 
`TestClass.SetError` is a member variable of `TestClass` that references an anonymous method. 
Which means later you can do `TestClass.SetError = function(){ alert ("SetError2");}`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has Objects and Functions.

An Object can contains Objects and/or functions.

this is an object:

```
var TestClass = {};
```

you can add a new object to TestClass Object as following:

```
var TestClass = { object : {}};
```

Then you can have an access to it like this:

```
var a = TestClass.object;
```

You can have a function in an object:

```
var TestClass = {object:{}, setError:function(){/*function body*/}};
```

Now you can invoke the function of test class like this:

```
TestClass.setError();
```

In addition, Function itself can be defined like this:

```
function setError2(){/*function body*/}
```

and you may invoke like this:

```
setError2();
```

usually, we define functions in objects to somehow implement OO in Javascript and prevent messy js codes.

Answer (score -2):

This:

```
function SetError2(errorCode) {
  alert("SetError2 ");
}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
window.SetError2 = function(errorCode) {
  alert("SetError2 ");
}
```

Comment: Not exactly... the first one is function declaration and the second one is function expression. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: @DmitryPashkevich I meant conceptually. Try this: `function foo() {alert("foo"); } ; window.foo();`. I realise there's a subtle difference in how they are handled internally by the JS runtime, but for the OP to understand the difference between his two cases, I figured it might help to understand.

Comment: Oh, now I see... But since the difference is really sublte and the OP is asking a direct question about it, I'd give him maximum information so he realizes it.

Comment: I think you're right. I likely misunderstood the question. I thought he meant what the code did, but he may be asking why there's a difference in syntax to apparently achieve the same thing. A bit unclear from the question actually.

Comment: I think that this answer is the best to explain why the function was not called as expected. And so many downvotes... how silly.