# Functions Declarations

Tags: javascript, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)
>   [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip)

What is the right way to declare Javascript Function?

From codeacademy.com i got this way:

```
var someFunction = function(paramA, paramB){
    // do some function here
}
```

But because my basic of programming is PHP, i prefer declare function with this way:

```
function someFunction(paramA, paramB){
    // do some function
}
```

What I'm concern is which one is recommended way to declare function, I'm afraid if my preferred way have some consequences, but i love that way so much because it make my NetBeans Code Navigator can read all of my functions.

[image: Netbeans Code Navigator]

Comment: Technically, only the second one is a declaration. See the duplicate suggested by Diodeus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are acceptable. Indeed, you can also do:

```
foo = function bar() { 
          console.log(arguments.callee.name); 
};
```

If you then call `foo()`, you'll see `"bar"` in the console.

The first method creates an anonymous function and assigns it to a variable.

The second method creates a named function and places it within the current scope.

The third method creates a named function and assigns it to a variable. However, this time, the name only exists within the scope of that function.

Declaring a function with a name (`function name () {}`) has the advantage that you can then call the function more easily from inside itself, as may be necessary for implementing a recursive algorithm. If you don't, you have to use `arguments.callee.name` in order to call a function within itself, but that is warned against in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee).

All of that is a long-winded way of saying that either is acceptable and, if in doubt, you can't go much wrong with using named functions.