# Trouble calling a function

Tags: javascript, function

This is my first time posting after looking through for a while and I am new to javascript, but I am having trouble figuring this out.

I am trying to call a function I have created, and everytime I attempt to call it...i am told I am not calling the function.

What am I missing?

```
//Simple greeting function
var greeting = function (name) {
console.log("Great to see you," + " " + name);
};

//Calling function
var greeting = function(name) {
console.log("Hello" + "" + name);
} // this was missing in the original question
```

or if I try

```
functionName = function(name)
```

I'll get a syntax error

Comment: It doesnt seem like there is a closing brace on the greeting function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What?! Try this:

```
var greeting = function(name) {
   console.log('Hello ' + name);
}

greeting('ktm');
```

---

So there are two ways to define functions.

(1) Function Expression

`var greeting = function(name) { ... }`

(2) Function Declaration

`function greeting(name) { ... }`

There is a simple way to call functions.

`greeting('hello');`

You can actually pass it any number of arguments, but if the function expects an argument, and you pass it none, it will treat it as `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you. I don't mean to waste anyone's time. I'm new to javascript.

Comment: You're not wasting anyone's time, seriously :-) It was my pleasure to write this response. I'm sorry if you mistook the (initial) jocular presentation as condescending.

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling your function at all.

A call to your function would look like this:

```
greeting( "Mike" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//Simple greeting function
var greeting = function (name) {
    console.log("Great to see you," + " " + name);
};

greeting('foo bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to define your function:

```
function greeting(name) {

    console.log("Great to see you," + " " + name);

}
```

and call it:

```
greeting("Tomas");
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can do...

```
/*here i am declaring my function*/
function greeting(name) {
console.log(name);
}

/*here i am calling it*/
greeting('ktm');
```

function greeting(){} is a function declaration.  Function declarations are probably easier to pick up and learn before you go diving-in, into storing functions into variables. Especially if you're learning this stuff for the first time.

Comment: I think it's not as confusing as it seems. The distinction is such a buzzword that it becomes confusing because you *hear about it* before you actually *learn about it*. The most effective remedy is a concise explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip

Comment: I totally agree.  But the beauty of learning a function declaration first is that it can be set anywhere on your JavaScript page unlike some other approaches, which is why I recommend as a first learning step, just in case you end up putting referencing code above it or below it.