# What is the difference between a Javascript custom data type and an object?

Tags: javascript

I am just learning javascript and was wondering if someone could point me to or explain a good  description between a custom data type and a regular class like object?

I was working through a sample code snip below to help me. Is a custom data type and a regular class like type object the same thing? I was confused on this point.

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;

    this.getFullName = function() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    };

    this.greet = function(person) {
        alert("Hello " + person.getFullName());
    };

}

var person1 = new Person("Bill", "Smith");
var person2 = new Person("John", "Doe");

person2.greet(person1);

alert(person1.getFullName());
```

Thanks in advance to all. Is this the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996735/what-is-the-difference-of-3-object-declarations-of-javascript)?

Comment: what is  custom data type  ? in js you can create object via Object.create / constructor functions  / literal object. what u did here is constuctor function

Comment: What is a "regular class"? JavaScript objects do not have "types".

Comment: It was my understanding from another language that I said class, referring to class object. The guy below got what I meant and explained everything to me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript, there are no classes ( *but OOP is possible* )

**1**.Primary data types include `Arrays` and `int`, `string`, `float`, etc.

**2**.Custom data types are also array kind of thing, except you can define properties and functions inside them.

Examples

For 1

```
var example1=1;// Example for the first one.
```

For 2

```
var example2 = {
    name: 'Hi',
    introduce: function () {
        alert("Hi from "+this.name);
    }
};
```

For the first one, you can just use the value or manipulate it.

For the second one, you can define what you want and you can also call functions, defined in that variable.

So, with `example2` You can do this:

```
example2.name='Joe';
example2.introduce();// Will alert "Hi from Joe";
```

Note that, while you define your custom object, you can call its properties and functions with reference to `this` as I have used in `this.name`.

Since you are a newbie to javascript, also note that you'll need to use only `var` to create variables unlike `int`, `string`  in other languages.

Comment: I know this is a super old post, but modern JavaScript supports classes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes