# Function sees only three arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is a simplified code that runs on Node.js [crawler](https://npmjs.org/package/crawler) and it gets all data.
But how do I insert inside the **"callback": function** value of **var "i"** from cycle for(var i=0... When I'm adding **name: datas[i].name** it returns an error:

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined*

```
var Crawler = require("crawler").Crawler;
var crawler = new Crawler;

var datas  = [
{name: 'John', url: 'john025'},
{name: 'Jim', url: 'jim04567'}
];

function crauler(done) {
for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
    var link = 'http://somesite.com/' + datas[i].url;
    crawler.queue([{
        "uri": link,
            // inside this func
                        "callback": function (error, result, $, datas, i) {
            var arr = $('.blogpost').map(function (index) {
                var str = $(this).attr('href');
                var object = {
                    numb: str,
                    name: datas[i].name
                };
                return obj; 
            }).get().join(',');
            done(arr);
} }]) }; };

crauler (function (arr) {
console.log(arr);
});
```

Comment: declare `i` outside the for loop.

Comment: @bfavaretto It's not. Looping variable isn't the main issue here for the TypeError, see my answer for details.

Comment: @jaux The error is caused by an attempt to solve the [infamous loop problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem), so the dupe link makes sense. BTW, nice answer.

Comment: @bfavaretto Thank you! But this issue really isn't the infamous loop problem. Infamous loop problem is that you always get the last value of the looping variable, but OP got `undefined` when trying to access `datas` and `i`.

Comment: @jaux When you remove the arguments that are shadowing the outer variables (as in your answer), then it becomes that problem. And one of the possible solutions is to wrap the callback in an IIFE (as in your answer). So maybe this is not a duplicate, but without a doubt the linked questions are closely related.

Comment: @bfavaretto After re-reading your comment, I agree with you, OP was indeed trying to solve the loop problem, the infamous loop problem should be linked here. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass `datas` and `i` into callback functions like this. What arguments that the callback functions will be called with are up to the caller, you don't have the control of it.

You're seeing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined" because *you* want your callback function to have `datas` and `i` as parameters; but the caller will call the callback with **the first 3 arguments only** [[crawler callback reference](https://npmjs.org/package/crawler)], so the `datas` and `i` are `undefined`.

Therefore, you should remove the `datas` and `i` from in line:

```
"callback": function (error, result, $, datas, i) {
```

Because `datas` is defined in the outer scope of the callback function, the callback can access `datas` without any special treatment. For the variable `i`, it's a little bit tricky as mentioned in other answers, so you need to create a closure for it.

So, your callback function definition should be something looks like the following:

```
"callback": (function(i) { // create closure for i
    return function (error, result, $) { // no more datas and i here
        var arr = $('.blogpost').map(function (index) {
            var str = $(this).attr('href');
            var object = {
                numb: str,
                name: datas[i].name // access datas as it
            };
            return obj; 
        }).get().join(',');
        done(arr);
    }
})(i)
```

Comment: Thank! All that nuances and nuances. And can you give a link to read about this style of syntax when function placed in () with some arguments after that. I see it for the first time.

Comment: @Ligamentum It's function expression http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to create a closure around `i` inside of a loop which is causing you problems. This answer should help you:

[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2):

You need a closure to capture the values, this is one way to solve the problem. Read up on [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Javascript

```
var Crawler = require("crawler").Crawler;
var crawler = new Crawler;

var datas = [{
    name: 'John',
    url: 'john025'
}, {
    name: 'Jim',
    url: 'jim04567'
}];

function queue(link, i) {
        crawler.queue([{
            "uri": link,
            // inside this func
            "callback": function (error, result, $, datas, i) {
                var arr = $('.blogpost').map(function (index) {
                    var str = $(this).attr('href');
                    var object = {
                        numb: str,
                        name: datas[i].name
                    };
                    return obj;
                }).get().join(',');
                done(arr);
            }
        }]);
}

function crauler(done) {
    for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
        var link = 'http://somesite.com/' + datas[i].url;
        queue(link, i);
};

crauler(function (arr) {
    console.log(arr);
});
```