# if statements not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return

I am new to js, I just wrote the basic function below based on the rock, paper, scissors game. For some reason the result of the compare function is always showing up as a 
"draw" rather than the other results. What am I doing wrong here?

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

choice1 = userChoice;
choice2 = computerChoice;

var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
if (choice1 == choice2) {
        return "draw!";
}

if (choice1 == "rock") {
    if (choice2 == "scissors") {
        return "rock wins!";
    } else {
        return "paper wins!";
    }
}

if (choice1 == "paper") {
    if (choice2 == "scissors") {
        return "scissors wins!";
    } else {
        return "paper wins!";
    }
}

    if (choice1 == "scissors") {
        if (choice2 == "rock") {
            return "rock wins!";
        } else {
            return "scissors wins!";
        }
    }
};

compare();
```

Thanks, Us

Comment: You're not passing any arguments to `compare`.

Comment: chek what random value it gives each time aand the returning value of the user choise

Comment: By the way, it's better to write var computerChoice = Math.random() * 3 and compare computerChoice in [0, 1) for rock, [1, 2) for paper and remainder for scissors: more precise.

Comment: by the way, i think you should use a matrix to determine the winner... imagine that you extend the game to `rock paper scissors lizard spock` (TBBT copyright), you'll have to completely rewrite you code...

Comment: either you remove arguments from compare function or pass the arguments when calling it

Comment: Thanks everyone!
@pataluc - Can you show an example of how you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling compare without parameters:

```
compare();
```

Therefore `choice1` and `choice2` both equals `undefined` and your game will always end up as draw.
You should try calling your compare function like this:

```
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

If you define a function, the parameter list defines the names of the given variables *within* the scope of the function. It's not a naming convention for the variables which should be available in the function itself.

Comment: `choice1` and `choice2` in the context of `compare` will equal `undefined`, not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the function with two arguments:

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2)
```

However you have invoked it with 0.

Try specifying the choices:

```
compare("rock", "paper");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn on function only by typing func_name() without arguments, thats like "dry shot". Read about [function declaring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip)

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
  computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
  computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
  computerChoice = "scissors";
}
choice1 = userChoice;
choice2 = computerChoice;
function compare (choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 == choice2) {
    return "draw!";
  };
  if (choice1 == "rock") {
    if (choice2 == "scissors") {
      return "rock wins!";
    } else {
      return "paper wins!";
    }
  }
  if (choice1 == "paper") {
    if (choice2 == "scissors") {
      return "scissors wins!";
    } else {
      return "paper wins!";
    }
  }
  if (choice1 == "scissors") {
    if (choice2 == "rock") {
      return "rock wins!";
    } else {
      return "scissors wins!";
    }
  }
};
compare(choice1, choice2);
```