# how to use javascript functions? (defining functions in label)

Tags: javascript

There are different ways of defining the javascript functions. I often use the simplest way to define the function

```
function myfunc(){
}
```

and the next way to define the function in the variable like this (a little bit confusing the way of using)

```
var myvar = myfunc(){
/*some code*/
}
```

and the difficult way for me and mostly found in codes developed by advanced programmers like the following

```
var SqueezeBox={presets:{onOpen:function(){},onClose:function(){}}
```

Please, can anyone clear my concept on this how can I use?

Comment: The second example isn't valid, I guess you wanted to write `var myvar = function() {}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: In the last one is an anonymous function how the author call the function or set some code for that functions.

Answer (score 3):

```
function myfunc(){}
```

**Function declaration**: the function is declared using the standard syntax

```
function functionName(params[]) {
    //functionbody
}
```

Using this syntax declares the function at the begin of the scope execution, so they'll be available everywhere in their scope(and in their descendeant scopes).

```
var s = myfunc(); //s == 0
function myfunc() {return 0;}

var myfunc = function() {};
```

This uses the pattern known as **function expression**, it just assigns a reference of an anonymous function to a variable named `myfunc`. Using this syntax won't allow you to use the function until the variable is parsed. Even if variables are hoisted at the top of their scope, they're initialized when the interpreter parses them, so the above example won't work:

```
var s = myfunc(); //ReferenceError: myfunc is not defined
var myfunc = function() {return 0;};
```

But the example below will:

```
var myfunc = function() {return 0;};
var s = myfunc(); //s == 0
```

The third example is just assigning an anonymous function to an object property(also known as *object method*) in the way we've just done with function expression, so if I use the pattern above the code will become:

```
var onOpen = function() {},
    onClose = function() {},
    SqueezeBox = {//curly braces denotes an object literal
        presets: {//again, this is a nested object literal
             onOpen: onOpen,
             onClose: onClose
        }
    };
```

This acts exactly the same as your example, with the only difference that here I used a variable to get a reference to the anonymous function before passing it to the object. If you need to know more about objects, I recommend you reading the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Anyway, if you're really intrested in how JS works, I'd suggest [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/), which is a very good article about JS.

Comment: can you please write some on defining functions in label

Comment: and what can I do for the anonymous functions.

Comment: They are just like normal functions, but they are unnamed, so they cannot be accessed without a reference to them. If you write `function() {...code...}` it won't be available anywhere because it has no name to be referenced.

Answer (score 1):

The first code snippet is a **function declaration**:

```
function myfunc() { }
```

You are declaring a named `function` called `myfunc`. You can verify this by `myfunc.name === "myfunc"`

Your second code snippet contains syntax error. I believe you meant:

```
var myvar = function() { };
```

This is an **anonymous function expression** assigned to a **variable**. You can verify this by `typeof myvar === "function"` and `myvar.name === ""`.

The third snippet is a javascript object. Basically you can think of it as a `Map` or `Dictionary<string, object>`. So `SqueezeBox` contains 1 key `presets`, which in turn is a dictionary that contains 2 keys, `onOpen` and `onClose`, which both of them are **anonymous functions**.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
var SqueezeBox={presets:{onOpen:function(){},onClose:function(){}}}
```

He's creating an object `SqueezeBox` containing another object `presets` with two  empty anonymous functions, he's defining the function inline with an empty body inside the `{}`.
A better way to see it is formatted this way:

```
  var SqueezeBox={
                  presets:{
                           onOpen:function(){/* empty function body */},
                           onClose:function(){/*empty function body */}
                          }
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered here: [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip).

For the last example, as Atropo said, it's affecting an anonymous function to an object. It's similar to the `var` example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of useful information on this subject [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression)

Functions can have a name, which if specified cannot be changed. Functions can also be assigned to variables like any other object in javascript.

The first example is of a function declaration:

```
function myfunc(){
}
```

Using the function declaration you will be able to call the function from anywhere within the closure in which the function is declared, even if it is declared after it is used.

The other two examples are function expressions:

```
var myvar = function(){
/*some code*/
}

var SqueezeBox= {
    presets: {
        onOpen:function(){/* empty function body */},
        onClose:function(){/*empty function body */}
    }
}
```

Using function expressions you are assigning functions to a variable. When doing this you must declare them before you use them. Most of the time you see this the functions will be anonymous but it is possible to name a function in an expression:

```
var myvar = function myFunc(){
    myFunc(); // Because it has a name you can now call it recursively
}
```

When doing this, the `myFunc` function is only available within the body of the function because it is still a function expression rather than a declaration.

The third example declares a javascript object literal, `SqueezeBox` and within that object there is another called `presets`. Within this object there are two more objects/labels called `onOpen` and `onClose`. This means you can do the following to use these functions:

```
SqueezeBox.presets.onOpen();
SqueezeBox.presets.onClose();
```

You can think of onOpen and onClose as variables that are part of the object. So it's very similar to doing the following (but the variable is only in the scope of the `presets` object which is only available within the `SqueezeBox` object).

```
var onOpen = function() {};
```