# onclick = Func vs onclick = function()

Tags: javascript, onclick, anonymous-function

like this:

```
    <div><input id="Btn" type="button" value="click"/></div>
```

---

```
    window.onload = function(){ 
        var mBtn = documernt.getElementById('Btn');

        /* 1 */
        mBtn.onclick = func; 

        /* 2 */
        mBtn.onclick = function(){
            func();
        }
    }
    var func = function(){
        var name="FirstName";
        alert(name);
    }
```

What's the difference between 1 and 2 ? thanks!

Comment: The first one will pass an event object to func. The second one will pass no parameters to func.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the only difference is :

```
/* 1 */
    mBtn.onclick = func;
```

Above, we use a **reference to a function name**. In this `func` is a name of a function declared elsewhere.

```
/* 2 */
    mBtn.onclick = function(){
        func();
    }
```

While in this,an anonymous function `function()` is being called where you can call any function or any code chunk.

Comment: mBtn.onclick = func
 is
mBtn.onclick =function（）{ 
      var name="FirstName";
        alert(name);
}

Answer (score -2):

[What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip)

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question.