# What is the difference between naming functions or not in javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

What is the difference between

```
settings = {
  edit: function (key, value) {
    return anotherFunction(key, value) {
      return value * 2;
    };
  }
};
```

and

```
settings = {
  edit: function edit(key, value) {
    return anotherFunction(key, value) {
      return value * 2;
    };
  }
};
```

?

Comment: You can refer to itself in the second function body

Comment: Checkout http://kangax.github.io/nfe/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential difference is better debugging. In your developer tools, the named function in your second example will appear as `edit` in a backtrace; your first example will appear as `anonymous`. This can be extremely confusing when you're 10 function deep, and they are *all* called `anonymous`.

Comment: This is a very good observation. I'm trying to analyze Ghost.js to see how a node application works and this might be the best reason the functions are named.

Comment: It really is. Everybody talking about recursion has missed the point. You don't need a *named* function to recurse, you just need a variable referencing the function. You can still recursively call an anonymous function this way.

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference when executing.

However, in the second case (named function), you can call the function recursively easier because it has a name.

For example, with a named function you can do:

```
fact: function factorial(n) {
     if(n == 0) return 1;
     return n * factorial(n-1);   //You can do this with a named function easily
  }
```

Without a name, this would be tricky.

Cheers

Comment: Err, without a name, it'd be pretty easy: `this.fact()`. You can easily call a function without naming it: `var x = function() { x() }`.

Comment: @meagar What if the function isn't part of an object?

Comment: `var x = function() { x() }`

Comment: In this case `callback(function f(n){  f(...); });` it's much easier with a named function (the other option(s) would be harder)

Comment: "Much" easier is pretty subjective; `f = function () { return f(...); }; callback(f);`

Comment: Yep, it might be subjective. For me, and I think for the 95% of the devs, mine is cleaner and easier (it's one sentence less), but more than that, _preferred_

Answer (score 0):

There are three reasons to give a function an inherent name. The first is that everyone does it.  It's what everyone is used to.

```
function factorial(n) {
    var accum = 1, i;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        accum *= i;
    }
    return accum;
}
```

The second is to understand stack traces better, as @meagar wrote.

The third is to let you write call functions recursively.

```
var factorial = function(n) {
    var a = 1;
    return (function factRecursive(k, a) {
        if (k >= 2) {return factRecursive(k - 1, k * a)}
        else        {return a;}
    })(n, a);
}
```