# Why does my load function not work?

Tags: javascript

I added a save function to my "game", but now the load function does not work.

```
function loadGame() {
    if(!localStorage.cookieCloneSave) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        player = eval(localStorage.cookieCloneSave);
        updateCookies();
        updateCps();
        updateBuildings();
    }
}
```

the load function causes the game to ignore any input as far as I can see, and it most definitely does not load save data.

EDIT: If I try to use JSON.parse() instead of eval() it doesn't work either, that's why I used eval() in the first place.

Here is the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TieSoul/Jjmdv/15/

Answer (score 1):

Change your `loadGame` function to:

```
function loadGame() {
  if (!localStorage.cookieCloneSave) {
    return;
  } else {
    player = JSON.parse(localStorage.cookieCloneSave);
    updateCookies();
    updateCps();
    updateBuildings();
  }
}
```

(`eval` is bad practice, use `JSON.parse` instead).

And define the functions:

1. `updateCookies`
2. `updateCps`
3. `updateBuildings`

because they are missing.

Comment: just to correct him ( in the eval part) : he should have done :`eval("("+localStorage.cookieCloneSave+")")` ---

Comment: the update functions are most definitely not missing and I have tried JSON.parse and it didn't work, which is why I used eval in the first place :P

Comment: NO. `updateCookies` is NOT defined in the moment that you use it. Please see the difference between [**function declaration and function expression**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip)