# Method of calling functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

So, lets say I have a little program that gives the user an alert that says Hello, that is inside of a function. Everyone says that you should call functions like this:

```
var thefunct = awesomefunct();
```

Yet it still works perfectly fine like this:

```
awesomefunct();
```

What is the difference between the two, and why couldn't I just use the second one? I know that both methods work but all my programmer friends tell me to use the first one. Why?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here.

Comment: What I am asking is this: there are two different methods to calling a function in JavaScript. (Both listed in my question.) which method is usually better to use, and if so, why?

Comment: Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run

```
awesomefunct()
```

You call the function. So when you type:

```
var thefunct = awesomefunct();
```

You run the function and assign the result to thefunct variable.

after that just typing

```
thefunct
```

Wont call the function. So there is not that much differencebetween the 2 other than that you catch the return value on the first 1.

Comment: Well, I am a JS noob, so some of my code may be off.

Comment: What you can do if you wish is "var thefunct = awesomefunct;" (without the () ) then you can later call the function by typing thefunct().. that way you create an alias.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the return statement of the function will be assigned to the variable `thefunct` in the first one, whereas the second just runs the function and doesn't store the return statement.

Say I have a function like this:

```
function doSomething(a, b) {
    return (a*b)
}
```

It would be a good idea to store the result in a variable, because the function returns the result, it doesn't assign it to a previously declared global variable.

Answer (score 2):

Do you care about the return value? Use:

```
var thefunct = awesomefunct();
```

Don't care about the return value? Use:

```
awesomefunct();
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be misunderstanding what your code is doing.

Writing `thefunct` is not calling the function `awesomefunct`, your function has already been called when you wrote `var thefunct = awesomefunct();` in which case `thefunct` now contains the return value of `awesomefunct`

Comment: I edited my question a little bit to get rid of this error you mention.

Answer (score 1):

The first type of function call:

```
awesomefunct();
```

runs the function, but the return value (if any) is not stored anywhere.

The second type of function call:

```
var thefunct = awesomefunct();
```

runs the function, and stores whatever the function returns (0, "I'm awesome", an object, whatever it may be) in the variable thefunct.