# Does the way a JS function is defined affect it's "performance"?

Tags: javascript

Is there ANY difference in the following two ways of defining a functions?

METHOD 1)

```
var printName = function(name){
    return("Hi! My name is ",name)
}
```

VS

METHOD 2)

```
function printName(name){
    return("Hi! My name is ",name)
}
```

and I mean ANY, I'm new at JS and want to lay down my understanding of functions and Objects before I advance as I feel these 2 features are the 2 I'll use the most.

Comment: AFAIK there is no difference (in performance) if both defined in the same scope.

Comment: Notice that `return` is not a function you can call, it is a keyword. Don't use parenthesis. And I'm pretty sure you wanted to do string concatenation, not the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), so use `return "Hi! My name is "+name;`

Comment: +Bergi hate to be a pain.
but whats the diffrence in using "commar operators" and a "string concatenation"?

Answer (score 2):

[Yes there is a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572), but none that would affect the performance of the function code when it's called.

Comment: Ok, for the sake of understanding, "what is the difference?" ;)

Comment: @RobRaisch There is a link.

Comment: @RobRaisch: That wasn't the question - if it would have been, I'd simply have closed it as a duplicate. No need to repeat this a 1000 times :-)

Comment: @RobRaisch here is a difference : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23013163/2324107

Answer (score -1):

The difference has to do with when the function is created, but the performance is identical.  Using your examples:

```
printName_1("Drew"); // This will fail, as printName_1 is not defined (yet)
printName_2("user4820485"); // This will work

var printName_1 = function(name){
    return "Hi! My name is "+name;
}

function printName_2(name){
    return "Hi! My name is "+name;
}
```

Functions that are declared using the latter syntax are initialized at the beginning of the block where they appear, so it looks like they can be called before they are defined.