# High order functions explanation when passing a function to another function

Tags: javascript, function

I need help breaking down line by line what happens in this example (an excerpt from Eloquent Javascript):

We have the forEach function which logs every item in an array. I understand how that works.

```
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  action(array[i]);
}
```

So we have an array called 'numbers' and another variable called 'sum' set to 0.
Where I get lost is when 'function(number)' gets passed into the the action parameter. What does that do and how does it work? I don't see what it's value is. Can someone break this down?

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0;
forEach(numbers, function(number) {
  sum += number;
});

console.log(sum);
// → 15
```

Comment: "I understand how that works" - looks like you don't.

Comment: It's a [*function expression*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1013385/1048572), creating a [*closure*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572) over `sum`.

Comment: Thank you! Mind explaining?

Comment: @Bergi can you please show me what you mean by that

Comment: The value of the `action` variable *is* that function - 101 of functional programming. Maybe you should just read on, it's well explained [there](http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter6.html)?

Comment: 'Since “doing something” can be represented as a function and functions are just values, we can pass our action as a function value.'

Comment: @Bergi I don't get it. Hence why I post it on here. To refer me back to an article I'm reading is not helpful. Thanks

Comment: What parts exactly don't you get? What parts *did* you get? Have you at least understood the basic idea? We can't explain the whole thing in minutest details to you - and probably you wouldn't get them as well.

Comment: @Bergi please see my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m575ffn8/ I wrote in some notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're not grasping the syntactic structure of the call. One could equally write

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var sum = 0;
function addToSum(number) {
  sum += number;
}

forEach(numbers, addToSum);
```

I hope it is clear what is happening in here. We have a function `addToSum`, and pass that function to the `forEach` function - where we refer to it by its parameter name `action`, and will call it with each element of the passed array in the body of the loop: `action(array[i])`. The great deal about this abstraction is that we can pass any arbitrary function to `forEach`…

So what is this odd syntax now? First, it is replacing the [function declaration by a function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013385/1048572). A function expression is just an expression that evaluates to a function object, just as the array literal `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` evaluates to the array object. It's also called an *anonymous function* as it does not have a name. We take this value and assign it to a variable:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var sum = 0;
var addTosum = function(number) {
  sum += number;
}

forEach(numbers, addToSum);
```

Nothing has really changed until here. Now, why would we need that variable? We don't really need those identifiers pointing to the values that we created with the expressions. We now just put the expressions directly in the `forEach` function call - still passing the same values (`forEach` does not spot a difference):

```
var sum = 0;

forEach([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function(number) {
  sum += number;
});
```