# How does a function gets passed in to another function?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a forEach function defined to do "something" with all the items in an array:

```
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  action(array[i]);
} 

var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0;
```

So I could do:

```
forEach(numbers, console.log);
```

And it would print out all the numbers because 'console.log(array[i])' prints the number to the console.
I get that part.

Here's where I'm stuck: If I pass the function below into the place of the action parameter, instead of 'console.log' then at what point does the function know about every element?

```
forEach(numbers, function(number) {
  sum += number;
});

console.log(sum);
// 15
```

How does it get evaluated? If I pass console.log into the last problem and it still has to be evaluated as 'console.log(array[i])' with the '(array[i])' code next to whatever parameter is being passed in, then doesn't that get applied to the entire function too since that function is the parameter? Such as below:

```
function(number) { sum += number; }(array[i])
```

Comment: P.S. You can't *actually* pass `console.log` as `action`.  It won't work.  Other functions will, but `console.log` needs to be called in the correct context (the `this` value needs to be set correctly).  You'd need to do `action.call(console, array[i])`.  Or pass `console.log.bind(console)` instead.

Comment: Are you saying you've defined your own forEach function? You know that already exists, right? http://dochub.io/#javascript/array.foreach

Comment: @RocketHazmat: It does work in some browsers where `console.log` is bound by default (which seems only reasonable)

Comment: @Bergi: Which browsers do that?  Chrome sure doesn't.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Opera does for example

Comment: Lets rewrite your code as `function action(number) { sum += number; } ; for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) action(array[i]);`. Does this code make sense to you? It's basically the same as you have, just that you abstract the `for` loop into the function `forEach`.

Comment: Related: [previous question about the syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26219919/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

> at what point does the function know about every element

At no point (just like when you pass in `console.log`).

The `forEach` function calls it on this line:

```
action(array[i]);
```

At which point, it only knows about a single value from the array because that is all that is passed into it.

(It also knows about the `sum` variable because that is defined in a wider scope than the function).

Comment: Ok, but at what point does 'number' from function(number) turn into (array[i])?

Comment: The function is called. The value of `array[i]` is passed to the `number` variable.

Comment: Ok now that makes sense, I guess syntactically it looks a little different. Not sure why this concept is busting my balls.

Answer (score 1):

> How does it get evaluated?

It creates a new scope (with `array`, `action` and `i` variables) and assigns the function to the `action` variable - that's a *function invocation*.

Your

```
var sum = 0;
forEach([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function(number) {
  sum += number;
});
```

is just the same as

```
var sum = 0;
{ // let's assume block scope here
  var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      action = function(number) {
        sum += number;
      },
      i;
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}
```

> If I pass `console.log` into the last problem and it still has to be evaluated, then doesn't that apply to the entire function too since that function is the parameter?

Yes, exactly. You are passing a function object - and whether get that by referencing the `console.log` variable or by creating it on the fly (with the function expression) doesn't matter to `forEach`. It only will get executed with `action(…)` - where the `array[i]` value is passed for the `number` parameter of your function.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, functions are first-class citizens.  That means they can be treated as variables, just like strings, numbers, etc.

When you do:

```
forEach(numbers, function(number) {
  sum += number;
});
```

You are passing `forEach` an *anonymous* function.  Instead of the function being in a variable, it's created on-the-fly.  Inside your `forEach` function, `action` will contain your anonymous function.

In for `for` loop, the `action` function is called for each element.

Comment: so it is really? is that what you are saying?

var action = function(number){
  sum += number;
}

Comment: @StackOverflow421: Yeah, basically.  The `action` in your `forEach` will be set to the function you passed as a parameter.  Functions are just objects.

Comment: Ok and when that function is passed in, when does number turn into array([i]) see fiddle please http://jsfiddle.net/zq5trh30/

Comment: @StackOverflow421: `action` is a *function*.  The contents of the function don't matter until it's *ran*.  When you do `action(array[i]);`, you are *calling* a function.  That's when `number` gets set; when you *call* the function.

Comment: I'm really confused on this, do you mind showing me on stypi possibly? for a quick second I just don't understand this concept.

Comment: @StackOverflow421: What's stypi?  It is a little confusing... I know.  Just try to think that, in JavaScript, functions are just variables (objects) like strings, numbers, arrays, etc.  You pass functions like you would an array.  Think of what you are doing here as a "function literal" (like an "array literal" or "string literal").  The `function(number)` is just treated as a variable.  When you do `action(array[i]);`, you are *calling* that function, so it gets ran with `number` set to `array[i]`.  That's just like `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the solution to your problems:

```
    function forEach(array, action) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(typeof action == 'function'){
                action(array[i]);
            }else{
                var slices = action.match(/(.+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/);
                var object = eval(slices[1]);
                var action = slices[2];
                object[action](array[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tested it with both scenarios and it works like magic

[image]

[image]