# loading of functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javaScript, started learning it a few days ago. So i was learning about functions and
most of the tutorials i was reading said that functions should be put in the script tag that is in the head tag so they can be loaded first. What does that mean ? Because I wrote this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function1();
function function1 () {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="HEY";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the code works. The thing is I don't understand how. How can you call a function that hasn't been "loaded" yet? Does the browser read the script tag in a different way than the rest of the HTML document? Can anyone explain how does it work ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1013385/3492895, http://stackoverflow.com/a/336868/3492895, think this should answer your question

Comment: Also script's don't have to be put in the head tag: http://stackoverflow.com/q/436411/3492895

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links guys, I am sorry I asked a question that   was asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly an optimization thing, `script` tags can be placed in many places (not only the `head`). In the old days, they are placed at the end of the `body` to optimize loading of the page and so the browser can show the page before parsing the javascript, so the page appears more responsive.

Now, javascript is generally placed in a separate file and it is recommended to place them in the `head` and use add either an `async` or a `defer` tag to them (you cannot `async` or `defer` inline javascript).

Declaring a function like:

```
myFuncName(); //Valid
function myFuncName () {}
```

Makes it available to be called in the entire scope in which it is defined. Meanwhile assigning a function to a variable does not allow this to happen:

```
myFuncName(); //Invalid
var myFuncName = function () {};
```

Sources and further reading:

- [Javascript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)
- [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013385/3492895)
- [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/3492895)
- [Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/436411/3492895)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are coding is correct script must be at the bottom

**According to Yahoo's Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site**

> **Put Scripts at the Bottom tag:** javascript The problem caused by
>   scripts is that they block parallel downloads. The HTTP/1.1
>   specification suggests that browsers download no more than two
>   components in parallel per hostname. If you serve your images from
>   multiple hostnames, you can get more than two downloads to occur in
>   parallel. While a script is downloading, however, the browser won't
>   start any other downloads, even on different hostnames. In some
>   situations it's not easy to move scripts to the bottom. If, for
>   example, the script uses document.write to insert part of the page's
>   content, it can't be moved lower in the page. There might also be
>   scoping issues. In many cases, there are ways to workaround these
>   situations. An alternative suggestion that often comes up is to use
>   deferred scripts. The DEFER attribute indicates that the script does
>   not contain document.write, and is a clue to browsers that they can
>   continue rendering. Unfortunately, Firefox doesn't support the DEFER
>   attribute. In Internet Explorer, the script may be deferred, but not
>   as much as desired. If a script can be deferred, it can also be moved
>   to the bottom of the page. That will make your web pages load faster.
>   top | discuss this rule

source: [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

**According to Google Apps Script Best Practices**

> **Load JavaScript last**. Many web developers recommend loading JavaScript code at the bottom of
>   the page to increase responsiveness, and this is even more important
>   with the HTML service. In the NATIVE sandbox mode, all scripts you
>   load are scanned and sanitized client-side, which may take a couple of
>   seconds. Moving your  tags to the end of your page will let
>   HTML content render before the JavaScript is processed, allowing you
>   to present a spinner or other message to the user.

Source:  [Load JavaScript last](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices)

Variable and Function [Hoisting in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

```
<script>

function function1 () {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="HEY";
}

function1();
</script>
```

Comment: "The defer attribute is supported in all major browsers." - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp :)

Comment: W3school is very bad never use it  http://www.w3fools.com/   please use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Browser_compatibility, seems pretty compatible to me

Comment: erm... by loading javascript last they don't mean:"call functions last"

Comment: I already knew about it. I simply don't see how the script tag loading has anything to do with this

Comment: @ towc well that s up to you if you want to write readable code and Fast, Memory-Efficient JavaScript. I will not force you to change the way you code but if you have time and want to learn more read this http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

The script tag is a whole block. The funtion1() was called after the whole script tag loaded.