# IIFE pattern named incorrectly?

Tags: javascript

I was thinking that maybe the name "Immediately Invoked Function Expression" is incorrect, because, in fact, what we do is invoke an anonymous **function declaration**, so the correct name could be IIFD (Immediately Invoked Function Declaration).

What do you think? Make sense?

```
// function declaration
function add( a, b ) {
  return a + b;
}

// function expression
var multiply = function( a, b ) {
  return a * b;
}
```

Comment: IINFE..!? (Immediately invoked *named* function expression...)

Comment: I also cast an IICVFBPOB (immediately invoked close vote for being primarily opinion based).

Comment: See [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip)

Comment: @deceze it's not opinion-based, it's wrong, so I guess you wanted to cast an IICVFBW.

Comment: @torazaburo I wish that actually existed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

A function declaration is a statement that starts with the keyword `function`. At any other point the keyword `function` is used, it defines a function expression. An IIFE looks like `(function() {})()` so the statement starts with `(`, not `function`, so it is a function expression.

Answer (score 1):

> what we do is invoke an anonymous **function declaration**

There is no such thing as an **anonymous function declaration**. Where did you hear of such a thing? Of what possible use would it be? It would be like a tree falling in the forest.

Try typing

```
function() { }
```

into your console and see what it says. In Chrome devtools I get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

This is not even valid syntax.

Why did you imagine that IIFE's have the form

```
(                       // <== MARK AS FUNCTION EXPRESSION
    function() {...
    }()
)
```

The parentheses are **precisely** to make this treated as a function **expression** so it can be called.