# Unable to vary linkDistance in network graph created using forceNetwork of networkD3

Tags: r, networkd3

I am trying to create a force directed network graph in R using the **networkD3** package.  Everything works well ...

```
devtools::install_github('christophergandrud/networkD3')
library(networkD3)
links2 <- data.frame(
  Source = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3), 
  Target = c(1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5), 
  Value = c(1, 9.9, 10, 8.8, 6.6, 7.2))
nodes2 <- data.frame(ID = 0:5, 
  Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L))

# this works
forceNetwork(Links=links2, Nodes=nodes2, 
  Source="Source", Target="Target", Value="Value", 
  NodeID="ID", Group="Group")
```

... until I start playing with the `linkDistance` argument.  When I set it to what I want, a function of the `Value`, I get a network diagram that consists of what appears to be a single node in the far upper left corner of the device.

```
# this doesn't work
forceNetwork(Links=links2, Nodes=nodes2, 
  Source="Source", Target="Target", Value="Value", 
  NodeID="ID", Group="Group",
  linkDistance="function(d) { return d.value; }")
```

I would appreciate any suggestions as to how to get the length of the links to vary.

I'm using R version 3.1.3 for Windows in R Studio Version 0.98.1103 with package networkD3 version 0.1.2.2.  (I originally experienced the problem using networkD3 version 0.1.2.1 from CRAN.  So I installed the latest version from GitHub, and had the same problem.)

Comment: I submitted this an issue to **networkD3**, github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/issues/37.  And I received an answer there from @jjallaire that works!  First attach `library(htmlwidgets)`, then use the `JS` function in the `linkDistance` argument: `forceNetwork(Links=links2, Nodes=nodes2, Source="Source", Target="Target", Value="Value", NodeID="ID", Group="Group", linkDistance=JS('function(d) {', 'return d.value;', '}'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a value passed through from R to JavaScript to be evaluated (i.e. to resolve a string to a function) you enclose it in the htmlwidgets::JS function. For example:

```
library(htmlwidgets)
forceNetwork(Links=links2, Nodes=nodes2, 
             Source="Source", Target="Target", Value="Value", 
             NodeID="ID", Group="Group",
             linkDistance=JS('function(d) {', 'return d.value;', '}'))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `networkD3` package is awesome!!

After an exhaustive investigation, I've tracked down the bug: The HTML/CSS/JavaScript code that is generated by [`networkD3`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/networkD3/index.html) seems to depend on [`d3js`](http://d3js.org/), which provides the `d3.min.js` file that is central to the generated web code. It is inside `d3.min.js` that the `linkDistance` feature is coded, and it is there that the bug occurs.

Unfortunately, as the file name indicates, that JavaScript is minified, but you can access the non-minified source from the `d3js` site, specifically at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/d3.js.

If you look at line 6307 (and surrounding context) of `d3.js`, you'll find this:

```
force.linkDistance = function(x) {
  if (!arguments.length) return linkDistance;
  linkDistance = typeof x === "function" ? x : +x;
  return force;
};
```

This function is called at some point during initialization with `x` being the *string* that you originally provided in your R call to `forceNetwork()` (incidentally, that string is embedded in the `index.html` file that is generated by `networkD3` as JSON data, along with all other input data).

To repeat, `x` is a *string*. This means `typeof(x)` will return `"string"`, *not* `"function"`, as line 6307 is checking for. Hence, the second alternative of the ternary will be invoked, `+x`, which is JavaScript-style coercion to `number`, which will result in `NaN`. Thus, `NaN` gets propagated through all the link distances and coordinates and everything gets f*!%ed.

This can be fixed by changing it to:

```
linkDistance = typeof x === "string" ? eval('('+x+')') : +x;
```

Obviously I changed `"function"` to `"string"`, but also I had to add an `eval()` call to actually pull the function definition out of the string so that all future code that works with `linkDistance` will work, because it all assumes that it's a function, not a string. Finally, I had to concatenate with parentheses to ensure that the function definition is expressionized, otherwise, if you used `function` as the leading token of your code string (which you did, and they did in the `networkD3` documentation, and that's the most sensible thing to do), then it would be taken as a function statement, meaning it would not be parsed as an actual expression statement, and the `eval()` call would return `undefined`, and you'd end up getting `NaN` when the code would eventually try to use the `undefined` value in arithmetic expressions, leading to the same errors. (See [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip) and https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/ for a couple good sources on this distinction, and there's probably a million other sources out there as well.)

I've tested the above fix on my machine and it works. I suppose this should be reported as a bug to the `d3js` people, but I feel I've done enough work here and can't be bothered. Feel free to report this to them, using my post here as a reference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure YOU are awesome and that this qualifies as an answer.  Let me just clarify a couple points.  (1) You are saying that without digging into `d3js` I can't vary the lengths of the links with the current version of **networkD3**, right?  (2) But, if I download the `d3js` source code to my PC and modify it as you suggest, then the **networkD3** function `forceNetwork` will work as advertised, right?

Comment: I just submitted your suggested change as a new issue: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2451

Comment: @JeanV.Adams (1) correct. (2) correct, although I think this would require modifying the `networkD3` installation, because I assume it packages a copy of `d3.min.js` in its installation. Obviously, you're going to want the problem to be fixed more permanently than in your current installation, so the bug report is the best bet.

Comment: This issue was closed on **d3js**, https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2451, *"Sorry, but this is not the right place to fix the problem. If you have a string that represents a function, and you want to eval that string to turn it into code, you should do it outside of the D3 API."*  I have notified **networkD3**, https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/issues/37.

Comment: I got an answer that works with the current networkD3 and d3js (see my comment on original post).