# How can I set linkdistance in forcenetwork in R?

Tags: r, d3.js, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I am trying to use `forceNetwork` in the [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) package. I want to define a `linkDistance` in order to set a particular distance for each node.
But I have a problem ([same as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446519/unable-to-vary-linkdistance-in-network-graph-created-using-forcenetwork-of-netwo)). The answer there does not solve my problem.

Here is my data example and code.

```
library(tibble)
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)

##Data
link_df <-
  tibble::tribble(
   ~source, ~target, ~weight,   ~source_idx, ~target_idx, ~linkdist,
   "great", "great", 1.0000000, 0,           0,          10.000000,
   "good",  "great", 0.7036672, 1,           0,          7.036672,
   "best",  "great", 0.3486529, 2,           0,          3.486529,
   "win",   "great", 0.2147706, 3,           0,          2.147706
  )

node_df <-
  tibble::tribble(
    ~node,    ~degree,   ~sent, ~node_size,
    "great",    0.6817043, "A",   64.789598,
    "good", 0.5037594, "A",   19.320302,
    "best", 0.4761905, "B",   15.425671,
    "win",  0.6190476, "C",   44.057260
  )

##Code
ColourScale <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
   .range(["#ffdd00", "#ff0000", "#0004ff", "#9500ff"]);'

forceNetwork(Links = link_df, Nodes = node_df, 
             Source = 'source_idx', Target = 'target_idx', 
             NodeID = 'node', Group = 'sent',
             Nodesize = 'node_size', 
             bounded = TRUE, opacityNoHover = TRUE, zoom = TRUE,
             colourScale = JS(ColourScale),
             legend = TRUE,
             fontFamily = "Calibri",
             fontSize = 20,
             charge = -400,
             opacity = 0.8)
```

I try this. But it didn't solve.

```
linkDistance = networkD3::JS("function(d) { return 5*d.linkdist; }")
```

or

```
linkDistance=JS('function(d) {', 'return d.linkdist;', '}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`networkD3` only passes on the necessary columns of your links data frame to the `htmlwidget` that it creates, so `d.linkdist` does not exist in the data that JavaScript is using. You can add back in the columns you want to the data in the `htmlwidget` before running it and then your custom JavaScript will work... (I had to modify your example so that it was reproducible)...

```r
library(tibble)
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)

##Data
link_df <-
  tibble::tribble(
   ~source, ~target, ~weight,   ~source_idx, ~target_idx, ~linkdist,
   "great", "great", 1.0000000, 0,           0,          10.000000,
   "good",  "great", 0.7036672, 1,           0,          7.036672,
   "best",  "great", 0.3486529, 2,           0,          3.486529,
   "win",   "great", 0.2147706, 3,           0,          2.147706
  )

node_df <-
  tibble::tribble(
    ~node,    ~degree,   ~sent, ~node_size,
    "great",    0.6817043, "A",   64.789598,
    "good", 0.5037594, "A",   19.320302,
    "best", 0.4761905, "B",   15.425671,
    "win",  0.6190476, "C",   44.057260
  )

##Code
ColourScale <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
   .range(["#ffdd00", "#ff0000", "#0004ff", "#9500ff"]);'

fn <- forceNetwork(Links = link_df, Nodes = node_df, 
             Source = 'source_idx', Target = 'target_idx', 
             NodeID = 'node', Group = 'sent',
             Nodesize = 'node_size', 
             bounded = TRUE, opacityNoHover = TRUE, zoom = TRUE,
             colourScale = JS(ColourScale),
             legend = TRUE,
             fontFamily = "Calibri",
             fontSize = 20,
             charge = -400,
             opacity = 0.8,
             linkDistance=JS('function(d) {', 'return d.linkdist;', '}'))

fn$x$links$linkdist <- link_df$linkdist
fn
```

[image]