# call to private in node with js

Tags: javascript, node.js

im using the following code in a node application and I got error when I call to _valdations function, I want that _vali will be "private" like (I know that this is not supported native with JS,what is the recomended way to do so ? the vali function should be not exposed outside (just use for internal ...)

```
module.exports = {


        fileAction: function (req, res, urlPath) {

           ....
                  _validations(config, req, res);




        },

        _vali: function (config, req, res) {

          do some validations
        },

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't export it. Just use it as a local variable.

```
function fileAction(etc) {

}

function vali(etc) {

}

module.exports = {
    fileAction: fileAction
    // vali: vali // Not exported
};
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin voted up !it appear that there is  two (like the other answer) options to do that (there is cons and pros for each usage ?

Comment: Named functions are easier to deal with in debuggers (since they'll tell you the function name in the stack trace).

Comment: Thanks,just to verify so this is the only difference ?

Comment: It's the only significant one in this case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip

Answer (score 1):

Just don't add it to the `module.exports`:

```
var _vali = function (config, req, res) {
    // do some validations
}

module.exports = {
   fileAction: function (req, res, urlPath) {
      _vali(config, req, res);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Constantinius voted up !it appear that there is two (like the other answer) options to do that (there is cons and pros for each usage ? or this is just semantic difference