# Why javascript function can be invoked before it is defined?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            f();
            function f() {
                alert('in f()');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

This block of javascript will work. But the following cannot:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            f();
            f = function() {
                alert('in f()');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

With the following error from Chrome:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: f is not defined
```

My questions are:

1. Why in the first case, we can access `f` before define it?
2. What's the different between the two cases?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3344397/772035

Comment: Read about **Hoisting in Javascript**..