# why function name will not be available after assignment to a variable

Tags: javascript

I just encountered this question in one of my interviews. I did not get any answer so putting it on StackOverflow

One simple question in JS but I am not able to get the reason behind it. Below is the code.

```
var f = function foo(a, b) {
    console.log(a + "-" + b); //f(1,2) will print 1-2
    //foo(1,2) is undefined.
}
```

Now if I do `f(1,2)` then it works perfectly fine.

But if I do `foo(1,2)` then it says `undefined function`.

Why this is happening? why function can not be called with functions name after assigning the function to js variable?

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

[There are two ways to declare functions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip)

Function declaration:

```
function f(a,b) { }
```

Function expression:

```
var f = function(a,b) { }
```

In function expressions, you can also specify an "internal" function name like this:

```
var f = function foo(a, b) { }
```

The name `foo` will only be visible from inside the function. This is normally used in recursive functions to ensure a correct self-reference.

Please refer to ECMAScript 5 specification, **[section 13](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_13)** for more detailed differences between function declarations and expressions.

Answer (score 3):

For a *named function expression* (which is what you have) the name `foo` is only available within the expression itself.

> [MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) If you want to refer to the current function inside the function body, you need to create a named function expression. This name is then local only to the function body (scope).

Comment: Yup. between name will be local to the function body only if we assign it to  some variable isn't it?