# When creating React functional components, is it preferable to use fat arrow functions or regular ES5 functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When creating functional components which is preferable?

this

```
const Search = ({searchTerm, onChange, children}) => {
    return (
      <form>
        {children}
        <input
          type='text'
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={onChange}/>
      </form>
    );
}
```

or

```
function Search({searchTerm, onChange, children}) {
  return (
    <form>
      {children}
      <input
        type='text'
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={onChange}/>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Babel compiles the ES6 version to

```
var Search = function Search(_ref) {
    var searchTerm = _ref.searchTerm,
    onChange = _ref.onChange,
    children = _ref.children;
};
```

and the ES5 version compiles to

```
function Search(_ref) {
    var searchTerm = _ref.searchTerm,
    onChange = _ref.onChange,
    children = _ref.children;
};
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Preferable in terms of what?

Comment: As far as I know, this is entirely up to your style preference.

If you are looking for style guides, everyone has their own. However a very prominent one amongst one of the big players is AirBnB which can be [found here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react).

Comment: not specific to react, this stack answers the question generally http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip

Comment: There's no such thing as 'preferable' here. You should know the difference between arrow function and regular function and choose one. In the context of this snippet there's no difference between them.

Comment: @azium The linked question is about declared functions vs. function declarations, not `=>` functions vs. `function`.

Comment: @Jordan if you look at the compiled code (provided in the question) you'll see the arrow function is equivalent to a function expression.

Comment: @azium Yep. Nevertheless the question in the title is "Is it preferable to use fat arrow functions or regular ES5 functions?"

Comment: @jordan Some question titles don't make sense once you know the answer,  as earlier comments are pointing out the nuance.

Comment: @azium That's certainly true. And, indeed, there is nuance to be discussed. `function` expressions and arrow functions are not equivalent, as the link in Bergi's answer explains, but the distinctions between them are not discussed in the question you linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's totally up to your own style preferences, given that no [other differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572) matter.

I prefer declarations because they are more declarative, need some tokens less to type, and will get hoisted. Only when using a concise body, arrow functions are becoming more compact.