# Function declaration vs function definition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can anybody please explain what the difference is between a function declaration and a function definition in JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: "function definition" is not a technical term in JS.

Comment: Maybe the OP means difference between function declaration and function expression?