# Is a function declaration (statement) also a function expression technically?

Tags: javascript, function, expression, declaration

The simple definition of an expression is "something that resolves to a value."
The simple definition of a statement is "an executable chunk of code."

With that in mind, since this function below resolves to a value of 6, does that make it an expression as well, instead of a statement, or both?

```
function ii () {
return 6;
}
ii();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip)

Comment: The function does not resolve to a value of 6. Why are you saying it does? You get the value 6 when you call it, but the function declaration does not produce a value.

Answer (score 2):

A function declaration defines what a function should do, as follows:

```
function ii () {
  return 6;
}
```

When that function is invoked as below, it becomes a function expression:

```
if ( ii() ) {
    console.log("true"); 
}
else
{
   console.log("false");
}
```

You can also have a function expression based on a declaration, as follows:

```
(function iii () {
  console.log(3);
  }()
 )
```

The following represents another kind of expression, for the value of a is the indicated function declaration:

```
var a = function iv() {
    return 5;
}
```

An interesting read on this topic is [here](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/).

Answer (score 1):

By your own references, **no**. The function itself does not resolve to anything, it just returns an already-resolved value. It's only a statement.

You are defining the function. That makes it a statement. Yes, you could say that calling the function "Resolves" it to the output, but it only triggers the output.

A value is more like an expression. It's not executable, it just *is*.

A getter is both an expression and a statement rolled into one:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "ii", { get: function () { return 6 }});
// Returns '6'
ii;

ii = 7; 
// Logs '6' because setting 'ii' does not change the resolution function.
console.log(ii);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So by assigning the above function to a variable it becomes a function expression? Since the variable will then hold the function, the function is acting as a value & that makes it an expression?

Comment: @Icepickel I smoothed out the text a little, better?