# nodejs function hoisting : why it doesn't work?

Tags: node.js

This works:

```
    var http = require('http');

    var handler = function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('Hello World!');
    }


    http.createServer(handler).listen(8080);
```

But this doesn't

```
    var http = require('http');

    http.createServer(handler).listen(8080);

    var handler = function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('Hello World!');
    }
```

I don't understand why since it should with hoisting all the more I got no error.

Comment: Because you haven't defined handler yet? It only passes variables by reference when it's an object

Comment: @lumio hoisting normally allows to define var afterwards so my question.

Comment: Hoisting only applies to function declarations and not function expressions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1169798

Comment: @Sirko isn't mine a function declaration with var ?

Comment: @user310291 but the way you wrote it, is that you define your function after you pass it. That might be the problem here

Comment: @user310291 You're using a function expression and not a declaration here. Maybe also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013385/1169798

Comment: @sirko ok thanks .

Comment: There is no function hoisting for a function expression `var handler = function() {}`, only with function definition `function handler() {}`.  In your function expression, only the variable itself is hoisted, not the assignment to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's not function hoisting, that's [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting). It's equivalent to this:

```
var http = require('http');
var handler;

http.createServer(handler).listen(8080);

handler = function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World!');
}
```

Function hoisting works only for function *declarations* (the above is a function *expression*):

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(handler).listen(8080);

function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World!');
}
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting

Answer (score 1):

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(handler).listen(8080);

var handler = function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World!');
}
```

In this case the declared function does not yet exist.