# javascript hoisting: what would be hoisted first — variable or function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, hoisting

Recently I was confused about javascript hoisting behavior and now I got stuck with that.

So, there are two examples.

```js
var alpha = 'alpha';

var beta = 'beta';

f(); //beta


var f = function f1() {
    console.log(beta);
};

function f() {
    console.log(alpha);
}

f(); // alpha
```

The first one is working as expected, because the function declaration overwrite our variable f (with value "undefined") when Javascript is set up the Lexical Environment.

But the second gives me a push, that I does not understand something.

```js
var alpha = 'alpha';

var beta = 'beta';

f();  // - alpha


function f() {
    console.log(alpha);
}

var f = function f1() {
    console.log(beta);
};


f(); // beta
```

Why the variable **f** did'nt hoisted to the top of out code, and overwrite our hoisted function before?
Why in *"first f"* call I recieve "alpha". I think, that it must be an error like:
"f is not a function", because in *first f* call I excepect, that the f would be *"undefined"*.

Comment: technically, the two snippets are the same

Comment: You might find [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3344397/6182569) useful.

Comment: Thanks for all answers.
Maybe this statement can help somebody who did'nt understand this thing like me:
So that covers variable hoisting, but what about function hoisting? Despite both being called "hoisting," the behavior is actually quite different. Unlike variables, a function declaration doesn't just hoist the function's name. **It also hoists the actual function definition.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `var foo = something`, only the variable declaration is hoisted.

This means that `var foo` is hoisted but the `foo = something` will run in the reading order.

Given `function foo() {}`, the variable declaration **and** function assignment are both hoisted. This creates the variable `foo` and gives it the value of the function.

If you have both of the above, then you declare the variable twice (for no extra effect) and assign it the value of the function (as that is the only assignment).

So in your second example…

The function declaration is hoisted, so `f();  // - first f` calls that.

The assignment of the function expression is not hoisted, but `f(); // ** - second f` appears after it in normal reading order, so the second call to `foo()` hits that.

Answer (score 1):

technically, the two snippets are the same

something like

```
function f() {
    console.log(alpha);
}
var alpha = 'alpha';
var beta = 'beta';
var f; // ignored because f is already defined
f();  // - first f
f = function f1() {
    console.log(beta);
};
f(); // ** - second f
```

or perhaps - though, I'm pretty sure `function` are "hoisted" first

```
var alpha = 'alpha';
var beta = 'beta';
var f;
function f() {
    console.log(alpha);
}
f();  // - first f
f = function f1() {
    console.log(beta);
};
f(); // ** - second f
```