# why a named 'Self-Executing Anonymous Function' not pollute the global scope?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

why a named 'Self-Executing Anonymous Function' not pollute the global scope?

chrome 75

```
//below is named 'Self-Executing Anonymous Function'
(function funcName(params) {

})()

// below is unnamed 'Self-Executing Anonymous Function'
(function (params) {

})()
```

As shown,an unnamed 'Self-Executing Anonymous Function' will not pollute the global because it has no name.
but if the function has a name?
Which has been tested,the named 'Self-Executing Anonymous Function' will not pollute the global either.

As is knowledged to all, the only way to seperate the scope is to define a function,but what happened now? the parentheses can do this?
Or maybe this is just a syntax-sugar specially defined?

Comment: Because it's not a function *declaration* but a function *expression*. You don't get a global entry for `someName` when you do `fn = function someName() {}`

Comment: There must be an existing QA for that...

Comment: @DenysSéguret it's a mix of a few. I'm hunting them down

Comment: [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript/8228308) [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip)